# Add Code Review to 'belongs on another site' now that the site has graduated

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration, code-review-se

Now that [Code Review has graduated](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/code-review-graduation), can the site be added to the community-voted migration targets list?

Current 90-day migration stats show that with 92 migrations and 9% rejections it is doing better than Tex.SE migrations (61 / 13%) for example.

On the whole, the community appears to understand that CR is for critiquing *working code*, so I think we can trust voters to migrate the correct post types.

Tim Post is [on record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191347/can-we-add-code-review-to-the-migration-list/191348#191348) of being in favour of adding the migration option:

> However, I'll go out on a limb and say that we'll very likely set this up once Code Review is set to graduate, possibly even before the design and such are ready. Of all the migration paths on the network, this is definitely one of the more obviously good ones.

Example question that I flagged for migration, but the OP self-reposted and deleted the copy here:

- [Not Well Structured Python Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733982/not-well-structured-python-code) (10k only), reposted as [Not Well Structured Python Code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68846/not-well-structured-python-code)

Other recent successful migrations:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699259/on-vs-on-n-for-word-frequency-algorithm?noredirect=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869648/bash-script-for-tagging-the-current-git-workspace-including-uncommitted-changes?noredirect=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658745/how-to-this-make-javascript-switch-statement-more-succint?noredirect=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641920/dividing-code-into-functions-is-it-good-approach?noredirect=1

Comment: Do you have an example of a question that would benefit from such migration?

Comment: I'll let some of the other mods weigh in on this as well, but I still reject a lot of requests for stuff to be migrated to CR.  We are pretty selective in what gets migrated there, that could be why there is a low rejection rate.

Comment: @bluefeet: do note that it requires a majority vote to migrate, while it only takes *one* flag to request a moderator-assisted migration. How many rejected migration requests were for 3 or more such flags on a post?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know it takes a majority vote to migrate, I was just pointing out that we do still reject a lot of requests to migrate to CR.  As far as how many with multiple flags, that'd be nearly impossible to answer since we don't have the ability to see any of those stats.  Plus the flags are custom so the content of the flag could contain a variety of things.

Comment: @bluefeet: sure, I'm just pointing out that your perception *may* be skewed; you have to reject single requests to migrate, while with voting such single votes would end up being ignored.

Comment: @Joe: see Tim Post's quote in my question: *possibly even before the design and such are ready*.

Comment: I just ran into one a couple of days ago, +1

Comment: Personally I'd like to see a free form entry similar to the duplicate selection, I'm just not convinced it's the best approach. Something like ________.stackexchange.com

Comment: My perception matches @bluefeet and I've seen a bunch of migration requests for questions that are perfectly fine on SO to begin with.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: that's an entirely separate issue, one proposed many times before and *declined* (for very good reasons).

Answer (score 41):

This request is premature, but discussing it is not.

Though Code Review's graduation has been announced, the actual delivery of that is dependent on factors that will likely take as much as a year to deliver. Code Review will only have the full graduated status then.

Apart from the premature concept, let's look at the list of successful migrations you indicated:

- [O(N) vs O(N * N) for Word Frequency Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699259/on-vs-on-n-for-word-frequency-algorithm?noredirect=1)

  This one is complicated. The actual question was cross-posted before the migration happened: asked here on SO at 12:35:54. Then cross-posted to CR at 12:40:48. The actual migration happened the next day, and the *migrated* question was closed as a duplicate. Note, that the cross-posting user is probably not the same user as the original.... the original user never actually joined Code Review.... so, there's a disconnect somewhere. It's a mess.
- [bash script for tagging the current git workspace including uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869648/bash-script-for-tagging-the-current-git-workspace-including-uncommitted-changes?noredirect=1)

  This question was a more than a month old before it was *self answered*. No-one closed it on SO in all that time, so was it really off-topic? Questions should be off-topic before considered candidates for migration.

  In fairness, this question should have been migrated sooner. It would have fared better.
- [How to This Make JavaScript Switch Statement More Succint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658745/how-to-this-make-javascript-switch-statement-more-succint?noredirect=1)

  Not a bad question to migrate, but note that the asker has never joined Code Review. The question was answered, and accepted before the migration ever happened. The answers are not great code reviews because instead of reviewing the actual code, they are "Here's how I would do it". That's not the same as a review. THIS IS AN IMPORTANT THING TO STATE.

  Typically, answers on Stack Overflow are poor answers on Code Review.
- [Dividing code into functions. Is it good approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641920/dividing-code-into-functions-is-it-good-approach?noredirect=1)

  This is a good candidate, and was in good condition to migrate, and got a good answer on Code Review.

Having gone through your examples, here's some migrations that have been rejected:

- [From multiprocess to multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657407/from-multiprocess-to-multithreading)

  (Question is a gimme-the-code question - please rewrite my process-based code as Thread-based).
- [improving an Sprintf for a micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811987/improving-an-sprintf-for-a-micro)

  (Question's code does not work) "To be on-topic on Code Review, questions have to contain reasonably correctly working code. Migration to Code Review was rejected because it fails to meet that standard. However, the author would be welcome to post to CR after fixing the obvious bugs first"

---

Having trawled through some recent history of migrations, it's worth noting three things:

1. There is currently a system in place where some SO mods are more familiar with Code Review than others, and they are excellent at filtering out what's good, and what's not good as migration candidates to Code Review. The flag-burden on Stack Overflow is large, and we appreciate that additional flags are not helpful, but, right now, the system appears to be working in what appears to be a reasonable scale, and time-frame (@bluefeet is my hero ... ;-) .
2. Migrations are relatively complicated things, but the general feeling is that they should be done more often than they are, and people on the target-sites should be more ruthless at closing and rejecting the crap. I believe this is a direct reason/cause why we have had two recent rejections. I'm OK with that. The scale is small.
3. Currently the amount of cross-posting and rejected flags are hard to quantify. Through various observations I can assure you that many many more questions are cross-posted, than are migrated. Cross-posting is a real problem. @bluefeet has been particularly good at migrating&flagging posts that have exact duplicates that were previously cross-posted before the migration happened. These are then merged on the CodeReview side. I imagine that many questions are simply deleted on SO if they were unanswered, or the answers would not be good CR answers.

---

All in all, when the time is right, enabling the CR migration target will likely be the right thing to do. It will also likely have to be a 'wait and see" game of how successful it will be. I don't believe there's a way to say "it will work" unless we actually try it.

As a mod on Code Review, the potential benefits would be:

1. faster migrations - specifically getting review questions *before* they get SO answers (which are crappy review answers).
2. more exposure to the the site, for both answerers and askers. Code Review would be an improved site if we had access to more people who were skilled at reviewing code, as well as debugging and fixing things.
3. better understanding of the difference between a request for fix-it help, and a request for skill-improvement

There are some significant potential downsides for Code Review as well, but it's not the place to list them. The potential upsides, if they are realized, will make the downsides manageable.... I hope.

### Food for thought...

About 10 to 20 questions per day are suggested as migration candidates to Code Review through the comments: [SEDE Query - Code Review Recommendations](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242495/code-review-recommendations?Months=6). Only about 1 question per day is actually migrated. Either the other questions are not flagged, or they are cross posted, or the flags are declined.

Scanning them, most of them are bad advice..... Just saying.... and, here's a list from the 'top 20' or so:

- Code does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684791/for-loop-to-calculate-monthly-interest
- Example, not real code: [Best way to hydrate/populate a complex object's properties for data transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684626/best-way-to-hydrate-populate-a-complex-objects-properties-for-data-transfer)
- Broken code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695908/my-own-linked-list-trouble
- Example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694362/mvp-on-simple-windows-form-application
- Incomplete copy/paste (not a terrible recommendation): [Problems with variables and scanf function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690388/problems-with-variables-and-scanf-function)
- Unclear question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687771/work-with-nested-task (Does the user want to return the value first, or does the user actually return it first, and wants to do it better?)
- No Code: [Sieve of Eratosthenes has huge 'overdraw' - is Sundaram's better after all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657213/sieve-of-eratosthenes-has-huge-overdraw-is-sundarams-better-after-all)

hmmm and also:

- Good Recommendation: [Complex Sorting a List of Objects Efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692902/complex-sorting-a-list-of-objects-efficiently)
- Good recommendation: [Faster way to calculate hexagon grid coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691097/faster-way-to-calculate-hexagon-grid-coordinates) and answer is good too.

Comment: SO answers might often be crappy CR answers, as the sites have a generally different slant on thing, especially on what's important. Still, a good SO answer can be a good CR answer, especially if it seems obvious the question should and will be migrated. (The only time I answered on SO and flagged for migration, the only other answer was migrated from SO too, and was a good CR-answer as well.) I really hope that's not the exception.

Comment: Added links to SEDE query for migration recommendations.

Comment: "Food for thought" or "Recipe for indigestion"? Looked so much tastier before...

Comment: "the actual delivery of that is dependent on factors that will likely take as much as a year to deliver" just a "year"? not "6 to 8"?

Comment: @Braiam - part of me feels that may in fact be a decent outcome ;-)