# Should code review questions be closed while CR is still beta?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, code-review-se

I sometimes recommend people to post their question on Code Review, and I see others do this too. So far so good.

But often people actually close-vote the question too, and I wondered if this is fair. After all, CR is still in Beta, so maybe using it should not be forced but only advised.

Comment: It has the potential to be in beta for a while, and after ~4 years of being in beta I think it's safe to recommend it to users looking for a code review.

Comment: Code Review [unofficially graduated](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2526/9874) this past fall, so it's not long before it's no longer a beta.

Comment: A site officially graduates when the new custom skin is done for it.  Since there's a sizable backlog of designs to work on, it may take a while.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As Code Review is [in the process of graduating](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2545/64289), I think it's safe to recommend it to users looking for a code review.

[Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/359284), the question needs to be [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Code Review and meet their requirements, not all questions do.

Comment: The last sentence deserves bold font.

Comment: @nhgrif:  I'd say that this is the one time that an `<h2>` tag is warranted.

Answer (score 24):

A note I would like to add about this:

Way too often I see people close-voting like:

> This appears to be off-topic because it belongs at Code Review.

You shouldn't *vote to close* because Code Review "might be a better fit". (You have read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975), right?)

You should vote to close *because it is off-topic on Stack Overflow*

There is some overlap between Code Review and Stack Overflow, *some* questions *can be on-topic on both places at once*.

Comment: Good point and of course you are right. But I think in reality many questions that are on-topic for Code Review could be closed as "primarily opinion-based" on StackOverflow.

Comment: @GolezTrol Then they should be closed as "primarily opinion-based", not as "it belongs on Code Review".

Comment: The option to vote to close because a question belongs on a different stack exchange site is a central and important option that is provided to you when clicking to vote to close. In fact it specifically prompts you with links to possible other Stack Exchange sites that might be relevant for the question. In my experience, Code Review should be available as one of those choices way more often than it is.

Comment: @Mr.F Please see [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276017/add-code-review-to-belongs-on-another-site-now-that-the-site-has-graduated) and [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1310566) about that.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I don't understand the relevance. The question of whether to specifically add Code Review to the list of sites that are pre-populated in the close-vote popup is different than disallowing migration to Code Review as a reason for closing. Not every site that should be a migration target must appear in the close-vote dialog popup. It would be nice if they did, but even when they don't you can still vote to close, select 'other' for the reason, and use a comment to explain that the reason is for migration to a different site that's not on the list.

Comment: The second link primarily points out that Code Review was in beta, which makes it really irrelevant. The close-vote popup doesn't even have the same options anymore as the picture in that answer.

Comment: @Mr.F When you vote for migration to the questions that *ARE* on the list, you're **NOT** voting to close.  You're voting to migrate.  If the vote passes, the question is **migrated**.

Comment: When you choose the custom option and type "I'm voting to close this because it belongs on Code Review", the question is **closed**.  And *sometimes* the user will post their question to Code Review... and often times, it'll be closed there too, because most [so] users are still pretty bad at knowing what's on and off-topic as [codereview.se].