# Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation, code-review-se

I regularly come across Stack Overflow comments which take this form:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

This has always bothered me. I've read the Stack Overflow help center. I've read the Code Review help center. Nowhere in either does it suggest that questions which would be on-topic at one site are automatically off-topic at another site.

---

Consider this query:
[OPEN Cross-site duplicate questions by same user.](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/282777/open-cross-site-duplicate-questions-by-same-user)

This query returns questions posted to Stack Overflow AND Code Review by the same Stack Exchange account with identical titles and only questions that are OPEN on both sites.

There may be some false positives (identical titles don't inherently mean identical bodies...but I did some spot checking). There may be some questions that slipped through cracks and legitimately need to be closed on one site or the other.

But, there are 304 questions in this result set, which currently is more than 1.3% of all of Code Review's questions.

Even if there are some false positives and some questions that got missed and need to be closed on one site or another, if there is just one that is legitimately open on both, doesn't this suggest that for any question, being on-topic elsewhere doesn't automatically make it off-topic here?

*Now consider that very rarely do the Code Review regulars peruse and make the sort of comments suggesting the question is better suited for a different website.*  Usually, it's Stack Overflow regulars making this comment, people who aren't necessarily familiar with the scope of Code Review, beyond the site's title.

---

**Are questions that might be on-topic at a different Stack Exchange site necessarily automatically off-topic for Stack Overflow?**

If yes, and the question doesn't fit any specific off-topic reason as defined by Stack Overflow's help center, would the appropriate action be to vote to close (VTC) with a comment like "this belongs on Code Review", or would it be better to simply flag for migration?

If no, what should be done with vote-to-close comments suggesting that the question is off-topic purely for the reason that it might be on-topic elsewhere? Simply leave a comment to the commenter explaining that this isn't a valid VTC reason?  Or would flagging the comment be appropriate?  And if so, how should I flag?

Comment: tl;dr but to answer the question you ask in your title: **no, there's often overlap**

Comment: I feel that way as well, and as such, I'm interested in the questions asked in the last paragraphs.

Comment: I generally don't flag for migration unless I am actively involved in the community that I am suggesting a post be migrated to. In any case,  you _can_ flag for migration but I'd but you should up-to-date with what that community considers an on-topic good question.

Comment: And assuming you're not-up-to-date with what that community considers on-topic, you should probably take no action? So, flag for migration or take no action.

Comment: [Here's my process flow in regards to migration/vtc](http://i.imgur.com/R7SiMnK.png)

Comment: "The topics overlap; accept it and mark the natural boundaries." –  [Shog9](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/current-state-of-the-job-market?lq=1#comment19869_6950)

Comment: Minor nitpick: The point of “TL;DR” is to provide a very short to-the-point version of a body of text.  “Very short” as in one sentence, 15-second-read, elevator-pitch, single-flappy-bird-round length.  Yours is ½-⅓ the length of the body.  Effectively, your title is already a TL;DR.  So I'm going to re-edit this to be an intro, and inset “Consider this query:” section, and then the last part.  Revert if you're vehemently opposed.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The fact that a question is on topic on some site does **not** make it off topic on every other site.  There is some amount of overlap between sites.  Given that, the close reason you've given is always going to be an invalid reason for closing a question.

Now, having said that, CR and SO don't exactly overlap a ton, so you'll find that good CR questions are unlikely to be on topic on SO.  However, when a question is on topic on CR and off topic on SO it should be closed *for the reason that it is off topic on SO*, and not just with a reason stating that it's on topic on CR.  If the user wants to comment that CR may be an option *in addition* to explaining why it doesn't belong on SO, they're welcome to do that.

Typically good CR questions are going to be too broad for SO (as they're typically very open ended and have no objectively correct answer) and they can also be too opinion based.  That said, don't just automatically vote to close all questions that would be on topic on CR as Too Broad without actually verifying that it applies to that specific question.

Comment: This is dead-on.  It's nice when you can say, "but even though it's not allowed here, it's *totally welcome* on [othersite].  But something being on-topic, or "more on-topic" elsewhere should have no impact on it being allowed here.

Comment: Do you have advice for convincing [a user that still insists on voting with the custom message despite multiple links to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318477/if-statement-running-every-second?noredirect=1#comment134608192_76318477) and then me attempting to explain how I voted? "_I understand and you're decision making process for why you voted to close it is up to you. I'm very comfortable with my reasoning and how I approached this._"

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ if a user does not wish to be convinced they are wrong, there's not a whole lot you can do about it.

Comment: That was my initial thought.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I tried adding an argument to convince them. If you are strongly confident that somebody is abusing their close votes, you can flag for moderator attention, and explain the situation, or bring it up on Meta (but anonymize the offending person as far as possible).

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship thanks! I have flagged some in the past [per Martijn Pieters♢ advice](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8839/should-vote-to-close-for-code-review-comments-be-flagged/8840#comment18410_8839)

Answer (score 12):

> Are questions that might be on-topic at a different Stack Exchange site necessarily automatically off-topic for Stack Overflow?

**Not always.** For programming related questions, there is often overlap between Stack Exchange websites.

For example, [Vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) recently started up and now most [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)-related questions that are created on Stack Overflow are [*most likely* on-topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Vi.SE. But [not all Vi.SE questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/572/89) are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

> If no, what should be with vote-to-close comments suggest that the question is off-topic purely for the reason that it might be on-topic elsewhere?

Sometimes these comments are made because Stack Overflow isn't the best place to get advice for the question at hand. Take code reviews for an example; while Stack Overflow can do a somewhat good job at it, CodeReview.SE is specifically designed to get detailed code reviews. Of course, we've gone over [this same issue with CR.SE before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286586/359284).

> Simply leave a comment to the commenter explaining that this isn't a valid VTC reason?

I'd recommend pointing them at one of the many posts on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Meta_Stack_Overflow) explaining that if something is on-topic on multiple websites, it doesn't have to always be migrated.

> Or would flagging the comment be appropriate? And if so, how should I flag?

I'm always hesitant to flag comments, because the comment queue is directly handled by the moderators. And since you can usually avoid bringing them in by just responding directly to the comments (or taking it to [Chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)), I'd avoid doing it for these cases.

Answer (score 5):

I would say no. I've asked a bunch of questions and I was thinking the same thing. I've asked C# questions about Arcgis on Stackoverflow even though there is a https://gis.stackexchange.com/ . This question got 5 upvotes and I never heard people complain about it being on stackoverflow. Maybe this is because the GIS stackexchange isn't that popular and nobody even knows about it, but I still think it could be posted on both. I've also asked questions about Magento on Stackoverflow even though there is a https://magento.stackexchange.com/ and at the time of writing this the tag [magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento) has been used: **28,730** times on Stackoverflow. There's just possibilities where it's on topic on both Stack Exchange websites.

---

If you do see someone say:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

I would just comment and say he's wrong.

Comment: Yea, it's akin to the [*tu quoque*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque) fallacy (*talking about others instead of self*). They should change it to "voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't belong on **this site**".