# Please don't encourage cross-posting :-)

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I would like to request that people don't encourage cross-posting to different Stack Exchange sites. In particular, I've noticed that on a number of occasions people get pointed to the new(-ish) Vi site with comments such as:

> See also [Vi and Vim!](http://vi.stackexchange.com)

I appreciate that people are trying to spread the word about the Vi site, but this often prompts people to ask exactly the same question at the Vi site, which is obviously not desirable.

A better comment would be something along the lines of:

> While this question is on-topic on Stack Overflow, there's now also a "[Vi and Vim stackexchange site](http://vi.stackexchange.com)", where you may get better answers to your question. Please note that [posting the exact same question to 2 or more sites is strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068), so please delete this question if you decide to ask it as the Vi site :-)

This of course also applies to other topics/sites :-)

Of course, if you think a (Vi) question is off-topic, then please *flag it* or *vote to close the question* if you have the reputation.

Thanks :-)

Comment: what you probably need is a [chatbot](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7154/new-se-chat-bot-feature-for-identifying-when-programmers-is-mentioned-on-stack-o) like one used by Programmers and Code Review to track "helpful" comments. And couple of active site users to cut and counter this garbage

Answer (score 9):

Cross-posting *can* be rude. Particularly in cases where someone spams their lousy question unmodified across many different sites.

But it doesn't kill kittens. So try to avoid freaking out too much.

Making folks aware of other sites that align with their interests is generally *a good thing*, especially when done with care. No one wants folks going around leaving such comments indiscriminately, but assuming there's a good reason to believe the author may benefit from knowledge of a related site, then there's no harm in letting them know about it. If the author then decides to ask a question there... Well, so be it.

#### See also:

- [Clarification regarding cross-posting rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87739/clarification-regarding-cross-posting-rules)
- [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Not "freaking out" :-) just a friendly reminder/suggestion on how to better make people aware of other sites.

Comment: No - it kills engineers across multiple sites as they all provide the same solutions for the immoral cross-posted questions.

Comment: such a nice attitude. Especially combined with totally ignoring all the requests to [help detect cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125139/165773) at sites damaged by "helpful" commenters

Comment: Not quite sure what this answer is meant to say - is it just the question reworded?

Comment: To be fair, the question didn't have a question in it...