# Is it OK to post your question on multiple communities?

Tags: discussion

Currently, I have a problem with Ubuntu that is programming related. So is it OK if I post my question on both Ask Ubuntu and Stack Overflow?

And if the answer is "you should only post on one": which one should I choose and why?

Question on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128161/rc-local-not-running-on-startup

Question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342601/rc-local-not-running-on-startup

Comment: Where does the problem lie?  In the code?  Or in the operating system?  Answering that should help you figure out where to ask it.

Comment: @fbueckert the problem is I don't know.

Comment: Then you need to think about it some more, and work on isolating where the problem might be.  It's not ready to be asked anywhere yet.

Comment: @fbueckert Shall do. Thank you.

Comment: @fbueckert:  It does kinda read like it'd work on Ubuntu, or even Unix and Linux, honestly.

Comment: @Makoto I don't know nearly enough about any *nix OS to say one way or the other.  I just think more effort needs to go into isolating the potential cause, and that will help figure out where it should be asked.

Comment: @Makoto I think I will remove from SO.

Comment: As i have verified that the scripts work

Comment: In the words of [Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295802/7795130): "Cross-posting *can* be rude. Particularly in cases where someone spams their lousy question unmodified across many different sites.

But it doesn't kill kittens. So try to avoid freaking out too much."

Comment: @fbueckert:  The question doesn't appear to be about programming.  The OP is trying to start Bluetooth up at OS boot time.  That's not really a programming concern, I'd say.  So, by process of elimination...

Comment: @Makoto Good logic.  But there's mention of a script, so...there might be something there.  I just don't know.

Comment: @fbueckert:  Okay then - I shall invoke my 13 years of Ubuntu experience to assure you that this is more of an Ubuntu problem than a programming problem.

Comment: @Makoto I defer to your greater experience.

Comment: The [canonical FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) states clearly that cross-posting is prohibited in almost all circumstances. In this case, the question is just off-topic for Stack Overflow, so there's no point in even having the discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No.

While some communities have some overlap, it is incredibly bad form to ask duplicate questions on different sites.

To help you narrow it down: either your question is about Ubuntu specifically such that Ubuntu power users can help you, or it's about programming such that expert programmers can help you.  There's some overlap with that demographic, but you should be explicit on the type of help you're looking for, and that should decide which site you ask on.

Related reading: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Removing it from SO would be enough to fix my major consternation with it...