# Can Stack Overflow notice a regular expression question and maybe suggest something apart from other like questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

The regular expression questions continue ad nauseam despite apparent [consensus as to the inappropriateness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/) of the general form. How else can they be discouraged or preempted?

Perhaps add into the "Questions that may already have your answer" box (which doesn't work well for these kinds of localized questions) a kind of boldly clear (and more concise) message that if you're asking about a regular expression that is not matching the way you expected, maybe you should try a helpful tool like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) or [regexbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) or something else particular to the language variant at hand. For example, [regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/?source=navbar) covers .NET, regex101 supports [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), Python, JavaScript variants, but note PCRE is not Perl nor Java's style so regexbuddy has those and just about everything else plus snippets. Or maybe you haven't read the FAQ parts (honestly the tour is no longer concise enough for people to read) about being [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

To be clear, I'm not against a question that asks about regular expressions. One could ask what's the best way to avoid a back reference, or use some other feature of the regex, for a given problem. Or: why does this language's regular expression syntax not support back references, are there other options for the language. Perhaps also those like: help me use named captures or branching uncaptured groups because I tried what I thought the manual said, but it broke with a cryptic message that didn't help me. Even "fun" ones like a stack overflow from a regexp.

However there's a good bunch of "I am trying to match lines with X but not those with XY and I want to know if that X line was an XtypeA or an XtypeB", and these are more popular in some language tags than others. It can drown out other useful, more general Q&A.

Comment: It's not clearly apparent that `icanhazregexez` questions are off-topic.  Some people don't like them, but they get asked and answered all the time anyway.  I'm not even sure they should be off-topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are they not clearly: "Plz write me something in a sub-language I never learned of my otherwise favorite language I purport to know, that does what I'm describing but am unable to show any attempt at writing myself?" They're off topic when generally not describing what if any research the supplicant did, and it would appear the answer is: no research. The other variant is: "I wrote this clearly basic mistaken attempt '[a-z]' but it matches 'abc123' which I declare I don't want it to do. HALP" That kind is too-localized, right?

Comment: That's what downvotes are for.  Use them liberally.  They're free on questions.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've seen your locked Question & Answer, which is very good. Do the people asking these questions see that in the "may already have your answer" box? It would seem not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey my observations in CV queue (23K+ reviews so far) suggest that this is just wishful thinking. Fastest gun rep-whores get to the question and drop their stuff over there before anyone else does anything else. And most experienced of them already learned to upvote question, to save it from _roomba_ auto-deletion. Add that often there are two or three "helpful" folks doing this and the chances of a downvote to make an impact get totally negligible

Comment: As a person who has asked for regex help myself because I didn't know the regex I resent that linked question, the linked question in that linked question even shows some code they have tried, I mean seriously, there is stopping coding services and then just not answering cos you don't want to, the latter shouldn't mean you stop others from doing so

Comment: Should we write a regex that gets bad regex questions? a metaregex?

Comment: `why does this language's regular expression syntax not support back references`  - that's a bad question too.  Features are not implemented by default.  The answer to *all*  "Why does X not support Y" questions is the same - because it doesn't.  Nobody created that feature.

Comment: @J...: There are design reasons behind decision to support a certain feature or not. There are many questions asking exactly that for other tags. I agree that this form of question in general doesn't always get answer, but when they do, it will give a peak into the design goal of the language.

Comment: I think regex questions are more like interesting puzzlers to those that answer them. More effort could be made to find a duplicate from common blunders, but many are specific 'what's the regex to match this" types questions, which could be migrated to [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), since the accepted answer is often the briefest expression

Comment: @Bohemian migration without editing to match [codegolf posting requirements](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ("objective primary winning criterion" etc) may led to question being voted down and closed over there. Bold moves like that are often not as [helpful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289949/prevent-im-voting-to-close-this-because-it-belongs-on-custom-close-reasons#comment175406_289949) as they appear at first glance

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is what a user currently sees when they ask a Regex question:

[image]

which links to:

- [The Regex Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)
- [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [The most frequently-asked Regex questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?sort=frequent),
- [RegularExpressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and
- [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/)

This message box appears when the word "regex" is placed in the title.  As you can see, askers already get quite a bit of interactive guidance.

Comment: Ah, my test case must not have been enough to trigger it then. That's kind of exactly what I'd hoped for... Do you think it's working?

Comment: It worked for me.  My title was "regex to change case."

Comment: My title was "I'm having trouble with this regular expression"; My content said: My regexp fu is weak. You can switch those around and not trigger this box. Also I didn't mean is the box "working" as in getting triggered, I meant does this actually alter the flow of questions.

Comment: "regular expression" is not a trigger phrase.  Neither, apparently is "regexp."

Comment: @dlamblin I guess that _regex_ triggering this warning could be improved to cover "regular expression" and "regexp". I am... somehow hesitant to make a question asking for such a regex at SO though :)

Comment: @gnat: You should write a regex to catch those cases.

Comment: @dlamblin. Well - it worked for me a few weeks ago. I'm very new to regular expressions and honestly did not know about regex101.com. I started typing, got the message, followed the link and played around until I got my regex to work. So that's one question avoided :)

Comment: @Cerbrus I thought one should [ask SO rep whores to write it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300740/can-so-notice-a-regular-expression-question-and-maybe-suggest-something-apart-fr/300741?noredirect=1#comment228504_300740), shouldn't one?

Comment: Shouldn't this also look for the regex tag?

Comment: @AnubianNoob: Tags are typically the last thing that is put into a question.  The popup appears when the title is entered.

Comment: Ugh. I open that [regex wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and immediately feel the urge to close it right again. It's a wall of text I wouldn't really read. That section "*How to ask regex-based questions*", which the asker is supposed to read, should go right in that help box (in place of that vague "*explain your question in detail*"), instead of being buried down in that wiki.

Comment: I wrote [this feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290740/3764814) asking for more guidance when you add the [regex] tag. Many questions don't have the *"regex"* word in the title, so the current message box isn't helpful enough.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You need to make it clearer that your feature request is about adding the balloon *when the tag is added,* since we already have a balloon.  You should also make it clear that your balloon differs from the one already presented.

Comment: @RobertHarvey to be honest I didn't even know about the balloon when I posted that. Someone pointed that out in the comments. I'll think about it and see if I can come up with something that merges these together.

Comment: Doesn't work on 'Reg Ex' either

Comment: @RobertHarvey - So the tags are entered last - so what? Only scanning the title and ignoring the question's body and tags eliminates all questions asked by users who 1) are aware of the [tag:regex] tag, and 2) know not to put tags into their titles. The popup therefore only appears when the problem it addresses is accompanied by another, unrelated problem (which it ignores).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I do agree that the process could probably use some fine-tuning.

Comment: Next trick is to cure balloon-blindness in those who just want to ask their question as quickly as they can.