# Recognize synonyms of "regex" in question title

Tags: feature-request, title, quality-filter

From [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300740/1830736), I learned that SO has a special blurb that pops up when a question title containing "regex" is entered.

[image]

This is great to discourage "plz help! write this for me!!1" questions.
However, it doesn't appear when "Regular expression" is entered.  This seems like an easy thing to add, and it should help catch slightly-more-verbose questions of the same nature.  It would also be useful: as of this writing, there are 123,817 questions that match "regular expression" when I search.  Not all of them are of the type that this blurb is meant to catch, but still.

Could the regex blurb be made to appear when one of the following is present in the title?

- regex *(already present)*
- regexp
- regular expression
- regexes
- regexps

@Braiam [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/230035) watching the tags as well.  There's a lot of regex-related tags, though, so someone would have to decide which ones indicate problem questions.

Maybe SO could use the following regex:

```
reg(ular\s+)?ex(p(ression)?)?
```

Of course, they could just ask someone on SO to write it for them if that one doesn't do the trick.

Comment: So, use a regular expression to recognize regular expression in a title... (yo dawg, I herd you liek...)

Comment: I was gonna add something to that effect, but I couldn't think of anything witty :)

Comment: @gunr2171 something like `regex[\w]*|regular expr[\w]*`?  Need improving but hey it's a start.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I made one that is a little different, see my edit.

Comment: This looks like a regex question about regex questions. Which is therefore rather meta, in a post on meta.

Comment: We need meta.meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I would prefer that whenever the tag suggestions detect that is a regex question the blurb would appear.

Comment: There are also abominations like ["regex expression"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22regex+expression%22) or ["regex expressions"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22regex+expressions%22).

Comment: You mean there are repetitive, redundant questions out there?!

Comment: @Kobi those would also be caught by the regex in OP's edit, since we're only looking for at least one match, rather than what the match is. Nice catch, and thanks for the humor!

Comment: You mean there are repetitive, redundant questions out there?!

Comment: I never knew about this! How is this blurb triggered and for what else is a blurb triggered?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty I was pretty disappointed when that didn't resolve.

Comment: What about "regular expression"?

Comment: @gunr2171 Now you have `(two)+` problems.

Comment: I think this has been suggested before, but I'm having trouble searching for it. I need a regex that matches regexes that match regexes.

Comment: No, you need a regex that matches regexes that matches "regexes": an important distinction :P

Comment: Wouldn't titles containing `regex` also contain `regexp`, `regexes` and `regexps`? So don't you just need `regex` and `regular expression`?

Comment: @MCMastery yes, but currently they aren't matching with a regex

Comment: Ew, capturing groups, really? `reg(?:ular\s+?)?ex(?:p(?:ression)?)?` - much better

Comment: I've never understood why capturing groups are the default. Usually you want a non capturing group. But capturing groups are so much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: OMG, what are you gonna do about typos? Or naming abbreviations comming from various libraries?

Comment: How about: `/\breg(ular)?\s*ex(es|p(ression)?s?)?\b/i`?

Comment: So, in the end, nothing was changed?

Comment: @DidierL Nope! I suppose it was added to a long list of "nice to have" features that aren't high enough priority.

Comment: @Owen Perhaps [at XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1313/)?

Answer (score 13):

Let's just detect the existence of regular expressions within the post itself with this simple regular expression:

```
/
^                                             # start of string
(                                             # first group start
  (?:
    (?:[^?+*{}()[\]\\|]+                      # literals and ^, $
     | \\.                                    # escaped characters
     | \[ (?: \^?\\. | \^[^\\] | [^\\^] )     # character classes
          (?: [^\]\\]+ | \\. )* \]
     | \( (?:\?[:=!]|\?<[=!]|\?>)? (?1)?? \)  # parenthesis, with recursive content
     | \(\? (?:R|[+-]?\d+) \)                 # recursive matching
     )
    (?: (?:[?+*]|\{\d+(?:,\d*)?\}) [?+]? )?   # quantifiers
  | \|                                        # alternative
  )*                                          # repeat content
)                                             # end first group
$                                             # end of string
/
```

How meta.

([shamelessly stolen from @MarkusJarderot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression))

Comment: That will only recognize *valid* regular expressions, which probably won't be found in the kind of questions we're trying to prevent.

Comment: This answer was firmly tongue-in-cheek; feel free to down-vote it as such. :p (clue: "simple regular expression")

Comment: @BenJackson If it's not valid, then surely it's an irregular expression?

Comment: This comment is a valid regular expression.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski LOL, great point.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: You probably meant to escape the dot, though\. Didn't you\?

Comment: @Tim, nope. The string *"This comment is a valid regular expression!"* should totally match my previous comment.

Comment: I would also like to point out here that people asking for regular expressions might not actually have written one of their own. And that a question contains a regular expression doesn't necessarily mean the regexp is the problem. Yes, totally fun at parties, hi.