# Can we warn on "belongs to SE site" as close reason?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, user-interface

[CodeReview's 2nd monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) has a nice little bot that tracks any mention of "CodeReview" (or similar) in comments. As you can see, [many of those comments are closing comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=voting+to+close&user=duga&room=8595), where the voters argue that the question should be closed due to CR.SE existence.

As [discussed five years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287400/does-being-on-topic-at-another-stack-exchange-site-automatically-make-a-question), a site for content `A` doesn't necessarily make `A` questions necessarily off-topic here. As [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287401/1139697) off-topic questions "should be closed for the reason that it is off topic on SO, and not just with a reason stating that it's on topic on [the other site]".

However, the current interface might be a little bit too forgiving, as "belongs to" reasons are just accepted by the system. **Could we please introduce a information box on those kinds of votes*?** (*votes that contain "belongs to") Something along the following maybe?

[image]
(Sorry for the bad mockup and text, you can probably come up with something better).

Note that this feature requests [differs from full prevention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289949/prevent-im-voting-to-close-this-because-it-belongs-on-custom-close-reasons?noredirect=1&lq=1). Any kind of ban or prevention is usually circumvented in any way and will probably only annoy voters. Instead, it should inform the voters and enable them to use a more appropriate close reason.

Comment: An alternate proposal I was about to post was to add these comments to the single NLN flag = delete list, because quite often they're just comments and not close reasons. Especially comments recommending Software Recommendations and Code Review are nearly always not helpful. But let's see if this gets traction first