# How can I improve my iOS MREs?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

I've been a member for quite some time now, mostly in Java programming, trying to move into iOS programming now.

When asking questions in Java, I exactly knew what was needed to count as an MRE, basically a `main` method with a way to isolate the problem, but when asking questions for iOS I always get confused as to what would be considered OK to post and what not, and what might just be noise into the question.

I currently have a question for a game I'm making, so if any of you could look at the format of it: *[SpriteKit keep moving player in current direction while falling after touchesEnded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666917/spritekit-keep-moving-player-in-current-direction-while-falling-after-touchesend)* and the previous question I asked: *[SpriteKit scrolling background image showing line between images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540829/spritekit-scrolling-background-image-showing-line-between-images)*, and tell me what can I improve in any future questions I might have.

Another question I asked before that basically contained a ton of classes is this one, where I had to post a GitHub link to the [Interface Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) files (.xib): *[How to show the standard number keyboard without a UITextField in Swift on viewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985448/how-to-show-the-standard-number-keyboard-without-a-uitextfield-in-swift-on-viewd)*

If my issues were about logic, non-UI related a playground might be enough, but when dealing with UI problems, how can I post those Interface Builder files or storyboards or how could I show it without linking to a GitHub repository with the MRE there? Or in the case of my game, are the assets needed?

I'm just trying to improve how I ask questions in this new environment.

Comment: No @SecurityHound I'm asking this question in order to improve my future questions, rep means nothing to me, but I'm curious about how to ask better questions when working in iOS projects. Actually I'm glad to have bounties when I really need an answer to any question I have but I'd like to help others to help me respecting their (and my) time

Comment: I don't see any way to improve the two questions you have asked about.  The newest question asked 13 hours ago, was only asked 13 hours ago, probably should give that one more time.

Comment: Not looking to promote the questions here, genuinely trying to improve, as I find myself posting a ton of code every time I ask a question in iOS here, because I don't know what should I post especially when dealing with UIStoryboards, among other UI things

Comment: For the current question, I would suggest putting the specific code for the jumping and left/right arrows first, then the full code. For the previous question, not really anything to say about it. I flagged it as "Not reproducible or caused by a typo" since its solution was unrelated to the code. The dot question looks perfect to me.

Comment: Wrong [meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Sinatr: The questions were posted on SO, where they're just as good a fit as on gamedev. I don't see why this would be asked on another meta.

Comment: @BoltClock, OP wants to improve his experience and I believe gamedev is the place to ask questions about games. Perhaps I should write comments more clearly, sorry.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with gamedev community @Sinatr however while my latest questions were more related to gaming, my question goes beyond that, I've find myself posting a wall of code (like the latest link I posted), when trying to show a MRE, which to me in my experience with Java is not ideal, everything was contained in some methods and a single class but what about when you have UI issues and you're working with storyboards and xibs? Then should I post XML? Link to a GitHub repo? I don't find an easy way to post proper MREs for iOS programming

Comment: No, you shouldn't post a link to a GitHub repo. Your question needs to be self contained.

Comment: And that is where my question comes in, how to show UI issues where you need to show constraints or that are related to UI + logic but the UI isn't created programmatically but with storyboards. You can't self contain them completely @mason

Comment: Sure you can. It's all in the [help center documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Include the minimal code amount of necessary to demonstrate the issue. No more, no less. If you've done that properly, you've got a proper MRE. If there's something you left out that was necessary, then it's not Complete. If there's something you included that wasn't necessary, then it's not Minimal.

Comment: @Sinatr Just because something is on-topic at another SE site doesn't make it off-topic here. If it fits within Stack Overflow's scope, then it's on topic and fine to ask about here. See [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287400/does-being-on-topic-at-another-stack-exchange-site-automatically-make-a-question).

Comment: Yes, in Java that was easy as if working with desktop apps the UI was built programmatically, with Swift there are 2 ways: programmatically which I rarely use and storyboards which are huge and weird XMLs that when read make no sense until put into the Xcode IDE and seen as storyboards, that's basically where my question lies, I've not seen people posting the XML for their storyboards, and when they post screenshots of their UIView then they don't usually receive answers or are too vague because people can't reproduce the problem without having a look at all the constraints

Comment: Imagine showing you understand the differences between Java and iOS, the whole idea of MREs, and your decision to ask on SO, by stating it all upfront... and still having to reply to multiple people clarifying things that any iOS developer would've understood and not questioned.

Comment: Tbh I've checked most of the profiles of people commenting here @BoltClock and none of them show any iOS question / answer, and if I had to guess, I bet 90% of the people who have upvoted either the comments or this question are mostly iOS developers who have encountered themselves in a similar spot than me. I wish there was a way in SO to probably upload those kind of files so we don't depend on external sites just to show them off, I mean, JS devs have fiddles / snippets, Java is mostly backend nowadays or homework tasks, android has their XML syntax clear but iOS... is a pain for SO's MREs

Comment: @Frakcool: Yeah, and I wish people were more understanding of that - that some techs are incredibly non-conducive to SO's rules and vice versa, and question askers are not to blame. I'm not sure what your overall impression of the SO community is, but I'm sure you know it doesn't exactly have the greatest reputation (heh) among developers. That said you seem like a pretty patient person, which is commendable. I've just been around much longer so I'm starting to show my exasperated-boomer side (I'm actually under 30).

Comment: @BoltClock well from what I've seen showing anger or being rude when asking for recommendations just gives you the opposite from what you want. And yeah I sure know about the reputation of SO, I experienced it when I wasn't even a jr programmer and was trying to get some concepts in my head and had some rude comments, learnt to deal with them but I started being more active 5-6 years ago with Swing framework that I love but not longer used outside of academics. And hey! I'm also under 30, 27 to be precise haha

Comment: But you're right, maybe we can't apply the same MRE rules to all languages and I'll have to learn to live with posting walls of code when asking iOS questions (or answers) and probably those will be longer than the Java ones I'm used to, at least until SO does something to improve the experience for those other techs

Comment: Is there anything to be learnt from current well received related iOS questions that you can use as a guide? If nothing else, it can lend further credence to a hypothesis as to whether SO tooling is sufficient to provide the standard you have delivered in java? The latter part it sounds like you kinda already have a strong feel for based on your SO iOS experience. Perhaps start a community wiki on what an MRE would look like for this; bit like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati#comment829803_405791

Comment: I wonder what iOS has to do with it? You seem to have moved to asking more UI related questions, and UI might require a higher amount of  example code, but is this specific for iOS or would it be just the same for all platforms?

Comment: As for the MRE, I'm not an iOS programmer but I wonder, are all private variables of the GameScene needed for the example? Do you really need a background and a floor? Is the name property necessary (maybe there could be only one entity)? Are two directions needed? One may be enough to show the effect. Is the up arrow needed for the example? These are all questions one might ask oneself when preparing a MRE. It really is not a simple task to create a truly minimal MRE.

Comment: @QHarr that sounds like an amazing idea! Thanks

Comment: @Trilarion UI with iOS is different than UI with Android or for the web, the way you build UI with either of them is different, so, this question is related to iOS UI building and how to post the MREs for when we have those kind of issues. As for the properties, perhaps the background isn't needed, but for the controls I thought left and right for testing was needed, otherwise you'd have to relauch the app over and over again as the node would be out of the screen (and removed from the calculations by the OS), and the up arrow is needed for jumping in this case where the problem was present

Comment: @Frakcool If the background is not needed, it should be removed. Relaunching the app might not be such a big problem, the MRE doesn't need to be comfortable, just working. I even wonder if an MRE here would need an UI at all. The problem seems to be with controls and behavior, not layout. A simulation of the control part alone showing a certain behavior and the description of the desired output might be enough; output could maybe also be given as debug logging output. In general, the MRE should be sufficient so that an expert in the field can recreate the problem and as succinct as possible.

Comment: @Trilarion Usually that's the case, but in a previous (now deleted) question, when I didn't include UI components I was told that they were lacking, so, as I mentioned, with Java Swing I was able to reproduce problems because the UI is built with code, not an interface builder, I'm on the phone, later I'll edit the question removing the background. You may be right that the UI could not be needed in this case, perhaps just a video showing what the issue is then the controls, and if asked for it, then and only then post UI elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after reading some of the last comments here are some things that should improve iOS MREs, I'll eventually create a Community Wiki as suggested by QHarr in the comments [above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406063/how-can-i-improve-my-ios-mres#comment832233_406063)

There are 2 types of questions we can ask when dealing with iOS issues

### UI related questions

These are the questions where the layout is the problem, in such cases we need to provide screenshots of our interface builder of the culprit `UIView` along with its constraints, trying to isolate the issue with as few components as possible.

### Behavior related questions

These are the questions where we're only changing values on the data, in case our code is modifying the UI (such as in a game) based on a state, we should post a video / gif showing the error and the code that is creating the problem, always trying to isolate the problem in a brand new project, in order to reduce complexity.

---

With the above recommendations, our questions should be self-contained.