# Revisiting migration options

Tags: discussion, migration

So the [canonical answer to perpetual questions regarding migration targets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) is essentially (summarizing briefly):

- current targets are determined by migration statistics.
- alternative options can be suggested by "write-in" via:

  - selecting "other"
  - flag for moderator
  - comment to the asker

However, I'd like to point out a few (major) issues:

1. As a long time and fairly avid user of SO, I was entirely unaware that flagging for migration was even an *option* until I started reading about it on Meta; given how many other questions are closed as dupes of the canonical I linked (and all the suggested dupes that pop up while I'm writing this), it seems clear I'm not alone in this.
2. This may just be a UI failure, but I've always read "other" in the current UI  as *"other than all of the above"*, notably **including** migration.

   i.e. my reaction used to be: *"Close > Off-Topic > Migrate > target missing, give up"*, instead of *"Close > Off-Topic > Migrate > back > Other > write-in"*

   Again, I doubt I'm alone in this failure mode.
3. The third option (comment to poster) ideally leads to a question just getting deleted and then re-posted on the other site, which leaves no data trail. ([most recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269377/how-can-i-improve-my-python-anagram-solver), which prompted this post.)

Given the above, I'm extremely skeptical that our current migration statistics are anywhere near correct, simply because things that are already in that list have an *enormous* incumbent advantage. In particular, I find it hard to believe that CodeReview wouldn't beat out some of the other present options.

I'm not sure what the best way is to address this problem, but it seems worthy of discussion.

Comment: Specifically regarding [Code Review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276017/add-code-review-to-belongs-on-another-site-now-that-the-site-has-graduated), I'd read this.

Comment: CR was eliminated from the list by request of it's users, as @bluefeet's link mentions. Too much garbage was being migrated there by users who had no information related to that site's guidelines. The current migration stats are calculated relatively frequently (I have no idea how often, but I've noticed changes in the options available), so I'm extremely skeptical of the conclusions you're drawing without any data. I've been aware of the ability to migrate since the day I hit the rep requirement for the privilege. It's been moved around a couple of times, though.

Comment: As far as #3, if the question was totally off-topic, the user was informed, they deleted it and reposted to the appropriate site, why do we need a data trail? The post was off-topic and should never have been here in the first place. If the existence of it's presence is ever needed for some reason, employees of SE (given a valid reason to do so) can always get it; very little that's ever posted here is hard-deleted, and those things that are typically are deleted for legal reasons AFAIK.

Comment: @KenWhite - I'm not reading "rejected by CR users" anywhere in bluefeet's link; the consensus (half a year ago) seemed to be "probably, eventually." Also, "many bad suggestions" isn't a convincing argument, at the very least you need to consider the ratio of good/bad migration suggestions. 
Also, I'm specifically **not** drawing any conclusions without data (although given the link, my hunch about CR was clearly correct), I'm just pointing out that our current data-collection strategy is likely to be deeply flawed; that's also why #3 is relevant.

Comment: Oops! Mea culpa - it was Programmers that raised the stink. (I should have followed the link instead of trusting my memory.) CR may not be there because it's still a beta site. I still don't see any evidence that *our current data-collection strategy is likely to be deeply flawed*, as you've not provided any. Your *hunch* isn't relevant. My hunch is that the analysis of actual migration patterns is much more accurate than "I have no data to support it, but it's broken".

Comment: Your reasoning is circular. "I know it's fine because the data tells me so" does not answer "the data collection is flawed"; it's like saying "Look, the top hit on Google gets 200x more hits than the first result on page 2, therefore clearly it's more popular". However things got that way, the current configuration by nature will distort the results.
Edit: Also, my evidence is the popularity of the question I linked originally and its boatload of duplicates.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm saying that you've shown no indication that the current system is flawed, and I've seen evidence that the migration sites have changed periodically (apparently based on the current analysis code). The popularity of the question you linked may well be because users that have no information regarding how the migration choices are selected are upset because the site they want to migrate things to (correctly or not) isn't in the list. "I want to be able to migrate questions from SO to <some site I saw in the list of SE sites but know nothing about myself>.". Programmers saw that.

Comment: Evidence that migration sites have changed does not in any way indicate that they changed _correctly_. All I'm trying to point out here is that we're **missing data** on what the best targets might be due to bad UI and lack of audit trail for deleted / reposted questions (the latter of which you accept). I can't really understand why "we should have better UI and data collection re: migrations" is so contentious.

Comment: OK. Apparently if I don't just automatically agree with you, I'm being *contentious*. I'm still not going to agree. I will point out that you have absolutely no information related to how data is collected (including whether or not an internal audit trail about deleted/reposted questions is used, which is certainly possible), and I'll say that the people who work at SE are much more knowledgeable about that process than either of us, and that they're not exactly known for being idiots about how to use their data for analysis. I'll now stop being *contentious* by not agreeing with you.

Comment: Chill, man. I was talking about the issue, not anybody's attitude. No offense meant.

Comment: There's no need for me to *chill*; I'm not warm. I just find it rather disingenuous for you to write *it seems worthy of discussion* and then say it's  *contentious* if I don't agree with you. If you didn't actually want discourse, why did you ask for it?

Answer (score 5):

1. > "I was entirely unaware that flagging for migration was even an
   >   option..."

   The page for [flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) does not mention the option to migrate at all. It states that there are sub-reasons for flagging something as off topic but doesn't say what those reasons are. I guess it's supposed to be self-explanatory once you get that far in the flagging process. Or maybe the list isn't always the same?
2. I also thought they didn't want us using the "Other" flag to suggest migration. I've just been suggesting sites in the comments. I don't really have a problem with doing that though; if the question gets moved, does it really matter who moved it?
3. Which sites misplaced questions get re-asked at isn't a good measure of which sites should be in the list of migration target sites anyway.

I wish I could recall where I first read this on Meta, but they don't migrate questions that are off topic or otherwise likely to be closed at the target site. That means if the moderators are going to move a question site 'X' they have to be familiar enough with the site's rules and scope to be sure the question goes there. *Those* are the only sites that should be in the list.

"Several users have had success re-posting their SO question on site X" != "The Mods have had success migrating questions to site X".

Comment: @KenWhite - I can see the migration options; the first line was me quoting the Asker. Sorry, I should have used actual quote formatting instead of just italics. (I just fixed the formatting)

Comment: You are right that I don't have close question privileges. In defense of my confusion, I don't think the OP actually uses the word "vote" or "voting" anywhere, just flagging. (Should I delete this answer then? If I'm totally off topic here, maybe I should remove it.)

Comment: @KenWhite: Those same five sites are available for flagging to migrate. It's the same list.

Comment: I think I had a good 600 or more helpful flags before I had anything like a solid handle on what the deal was with migration. And it was only in the last few weeks that I discovered that you're supposed to double-flag/close-and-flag for many migration cases: once to make sure it's closed as off-topic, and once to have a diamond actually migrate it.

Comment: @Nathan: Thanks. Sometimes it's difficult to remember what was available at certain points. I'll do some comment cleanup.