# How are the sites that appear in the "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" dialog chosen?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

Is there a particular reason for the choice of SE sites that you can migrate an off-topic question to?

[image]

I mean, I can understand meta and superuser, and judging by [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/1016716), there are a lot of migratable DBA questions as well, but personally I have never encountered a question that was OT on SO, but would be on topic in TeX or Cross Validated.

(Note, by the way, that my question is not a duplicate of that one; I'm not asking for an "Other ..." option.)

So, what's the reason behind the choice for TeX and Cross Validated?

Oh, I think it would help if I could see a data query on the SO database which questions were migrated where, but I have no idea what tables I should be looking in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flagging migration should include more options](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options), which links to [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

Comment: @Cerbrus No no, I'm not asking for more options! I'm asking how come these sites are mentioned, when I never encountered a question that could be migrated to them.

Comment: From Jeff's answer on the linked Meta.SE question: _"There should be 4 most frequently correct destinations + meta."_ <-- That's why those 4 were chosen, apparently.

Comment: Any statistics available about how questions are migrated in the Stackexchange network would be cool.

Comment: @Trilarion such stats are available to 10K users (note OP has over 10K and can see them) - [http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=migrated](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=migrated)

Comment: @gnat Nice. For the 10k users. You could have left me out of the notification. I'm not yet there. :)

Comment: Like many of the arbitrary decisions on Stack Overflow: because Jeff said so seven years ago.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Just read your comment in the other thread about that this is a [self-reenforcing popularity contest](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options#comment63597_251654), Wanted to say the same here, but you were two years earlier. Could only upvote it. :)

Comment: Btw. maybe the questioner or anyone with 10k could look into the statistics and confirm that the listed target sites are indeed still the most popular and successful targets. Also a few numbers about how often this actually occurs would be good, so we can estimate if the questioner should have seen such a case.

Comment: For some reason tex.se and stats.se have never thrown a hissy-fit over getting garbage from SO.  Like serverfault.se did, the reason they are not in the list.  Probably because they get so little in the first place.

Comment: I've [pulled the migration stats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cBgSv.png) for the last 90 days from the [trats page](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats). 4 of the top 4 targets are represented in the current close dialog.

Comment: @gnat and Cerbrus thanks for the links! I wasn't aware of those, and in fact I still wouldn't know how to get there by myself... Maybe one of you should post an answer. None of the answers (to the related questions) have those links.

Comment: @HansPassant Server Fault folks made [loud complaints at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150206/165773 "'Regarding the high number of rejected migrations from Stack Overflow to Server Fault'") about SO morons misusing migration dialog to dump inappropriate questions at their site. In the end, Shog had to remove SF from the dialog to stop the abuse

Comment: @gnat on the gripping hand, we have no rejected from the only 5 migrated on the last 90 days... so, I say that closevoters were abusing.

Comment: @gnat The Stack Overflow user interface doesn't exactly go out of its way to introduce people to how close votes work or what the usage guidelines are. Much of the usage information is scattered in not always easy to find meta posts and the actual "help" pages are rather bare and sometimes downright incomplete. These are people who are spending their free time doing the rather boring task of cleaning out the trash, and describing them in terms of "morons", "misuse", and "abuse" is not particularly helpful....

Comment: ...If lots of well-intentioned people who are **trying to help** are doing something wrong, then it's probably a good bet there's something broken *in the system* somewhere, and not in the "morons" who are "abusing".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I can only agree with that if you mean, "the system gives too much power to morons". Sure, sure, well-intentioned morons, but still.

Comment: but most topics are simply closed and not even migrated. I would remove the normal close and extend the migration dialog more.

Comment: @Braiam not having it available as a flag for migration probably has a lot to do with stopping the crap.  Normal users can't trigger it and at this point SO's moderators (who can migrate to anywhere) know what ServerFault is willing to accept and aren't trying to migrate every crap question that's even vaguely about installing some piece of software on a server.

Comment: @MrLister I would say "misinformed" or "ignorant". That's not the same as "moron". You can't expect people to abide by rules they don't know about.

Comment: Why not just allow an "other" site to be typed in and validate it against the actual list of sites, provide a drop-down for "other" sites, or something similar?

Comment: @EricJ. [SF folks would likely object](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318521/how-are-the-sites-that-appear-in-the-belongs-on-another-site-in-the-stack-excha/318535#comment318958_318521) and Programmers folks would probably object too

Comment: I often wonder if it would be more useful to factor in the tags of the question when presenting the migration options. For example, a question tagged `wordpress` is unlikely to be migrated to superuser, tex or stats, but could quite possible be a candidate to be moved to wordpress.se.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've pulled the migration statistics for the last 90 days from the [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) page:

[image]

4 of the top 5 migrations are represented in the current close vote dialog. The only missing like is at position 7 in the migration statistics for the last 90 days.

Here's the code, for your convenience:

```js
var results = $.map($('table[width] td+td>div'), function(e){
    var info = e.querySelector('.migrated-info').textContent.split(/[\n\r]+/g);
    return {
        target: e.querySelector('img+span+img').title,
        migrated: parseInt(info[0].replace('×', '').trim()),
        rejected: parseInt(info[2] && info[2].split('%')[0]) || null
    };
});
console.table(results);
```

Comment: I didn't knew the console could print pretty tables...

Comment: [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and [Software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) should be in flagging list. I saw many questions which could be migrated but dint had option so i didn't flag. These questions can be solved there but here they get closed.

Comment: @Sandeep SoftRecs is in beta, and while in beta you won't get migration paths. Codereview guys are against because SO folks have repeatedly demonstrated they can't recognize a good codereview question.

Comment: @Braiam I dint knew about that, thanks for info.

Comment: Ah, and I see it's been reopened too. Thanks! So, apparently the reason I never encountered a dba question is because those are simply outside my area of interest or something.

Comment: @MrLister: That's a possible reason, indeed.

Comment: @Braiam: It's pretty nify. Columns are resize-able, and sortable. Ideal in this case.

Comment: @Braiam Software Recommendations is not in beta, but we're not sure we can trust SO users to migrate *high quality* questions to us.

Comment: But aren't these numbers influenced by the choices offered in the migration dialog? Making certain options easy-to-use and then finding that they are the most often used options is a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: @m69: the premise of this question is that the OP has never found any use for some of the migration options. The data shows that the OP's experience is not typical, i.e. the existing migration options are useful to other people. It's possible that a different set of migration options would be equally or perhaps more useful, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @m69: Possibly, but at the time these migration targets were chosen, similar statistics were used to chose them.

Comment: @Martha I find myself often suggesting migration to dsp.stackexchange.com. It probably depends a lot on which tags you follow.

Comment: Just to note, "migrated" is in number of posts, but "rejected" is in percentages. Before coming to this realization, I was horrified to see 1 migration and 100 rejections on meta.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: @gsamaras It will not. Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276038/1014587) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311349/1014587).

Comment: To be honest I would like a CV reason that gives me a list of such sites to choose from that **doesn't** try to migrate it there. Because it's true; we see a lot of questions that should be asked on other sites, but are crappy or otherwise not appropriate in their current form. So we should be able to let the OP know "wrong place" and then if OP wants to re-post a crappy question on the correct site... it's their question to close as too broad/POB/etc.

Comment: Or just let us migrate anyway, because other sites insisting that we be the catch all for their bad-quality questions is unfair, in my opinion.

Comment: @TylerH If the question is crappy, there is no need for migration even if it would be more on topic there than here. It would still be crappy on the other site! So why not close and delete it immediately, rather than migrate first and then close and delete.

Comment: @MrLister Why not? Well, for organizational purposes and to ever-so-slowly teach the masses what site they should post their crappy question to, of course! Currently SO gets the lion's share of crappy questions that belong on a different site, so SO has to take care of them. They should be posting these questions to the appropriate site, so that the appropriate site can take care of them. After all, some questions that we would call utter crap are considered high quality on certain other sites in the network. Far be it from SO users to determine if a question is crappy by a diff. site's marks.

Comment: @TylerH I beg to differ, but let's just agree to disagree. Don't feel like chatting now.

Comment: @MrLister The whole argument can be summed up as "would you rather keep wasting more of SO users' time or share the load of responsibility with users of more appropriate sites?" There's no objectively right or wrong answer, just what the community as a whole tends to lean toward.

Comment: @TylerH You don't need a list.  You can just type a comment to the OP.  The point of the list is _solely_ to allow migration.

Comment: @Joe A comment does not close a question. That would introducing a 3rd option to this discussion: a regression.

Comment: ... you can close a question AND put a comment.  Closing a question, in fact, comes with an 'other reason' option which provides a place for you to do this.

Comment: It's been my experience that almost every question I encounter for which the gist of the question would be on-topic somewhere else, the question itself is so horribly written as to make it not worth migrating. I've seen where people instead have left a comment to the effect of "this question is off-topic here, but if you clean it up (a lot), you might have some luck posting it on xyz.SE."

Comment: Query to get fresh stats: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/843628/which-sites-were-questions-migrated-to-enter-number-of-years-to-query