# "Closing as off-topic" Update for Wrong Language

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, portuguese-stack-overflow, localization

The "Close" dialog would benefit from options to redirect people to the appropriately localized Stack Overflow site. There's several now and yet with regularity there's Russian, Spanish and Portguese questions being asked.

Right now there's several options, none of which are addressed in the Close dialog:

- [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com)
- [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)
- [Portguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)
- [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Having these as an additional "Closing > Off-Topic" section for the various localized sites would help. Right now it's a manual process to bump these people through to their appropriate home and a lack of properly localized errors could be confusing to people in the wrong place.

An explicit **This question is not English and is off-topic** options with links to these other sites would help considerably. This wouldn't require any judgement when making a close vote other than assessing that it's clearly not English.

Additionally, listing these as options in the top bar or with better placement in the footer might avoid a lot of these mis-categorizations in the first place. Finding the Spanish site from the English one requires clicking a link in the footer, then finding it a fairly randomly organized list of other sites.

Comment: Isn't that why we have "Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)"?  While I do see this from time to time, that wouldn't be top of my off-topic reason wish list.

Comment: There's inexplicably an option to redirect to the LaTeX site, of which I have seen zero legitimate cases for in all my years using Stack Overflow, but nothing for Spanish which pops up several times per day. These sites exist, they have users, they should get some representation in the close dialog. I'm asking for this feature because I can't be the only one that's had to do this dozens of times in the last month alone.

Comment: @tadman - While you may not have personally seen many cases of TeX questions, I regularly handle migrations to that site. It is in the current migration targets because it has a high rate of accepted migrations, and you can see in the query here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318535/19679 that it was 7th overall in number of migrated questions over that time period.

Comment: @BradLarson It seems unusually prominent in the list. Are these ordered by popularity or is it an artifact of when there were only a handful of Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @BradLarson I think that list is skewed because most people I interact with delete and re-post, there's never a migration, and a *lot* of them are sent to Server Fault and Super User, more than the handful shown there. Firewall configuration, Apache/Nginx server setup questions are extremely common.

Comment: @tadman I don't think the order is particularly meaningful.  I suspect it's the order they were added to the migration list, simply because no one felt the need to provide a particular ordering.  It's certainly not in the order of number of recent migrations.

Comment: The list is indeed skewed due to the presence of some migration paths in the default list. Many more questions would be migrated to Server Fault or Software Engineering if they were still there, but people didn't understand the scopes of those sites and the result was [large numbers of poor migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150206/regarding-the-high-number-of-rejected-migrations-from-stack-overflow-to-server-f). In many cases, someone is indeed better off to delete their SO question, read the target site scope, and re-ask their question newly worded for the target site.

Comment: @tadman Server fault was removed from the migration list because it has such an abysmal migration rate; an extremely high percentage of migrated questions were rejected after being migrated.  Some effort was spent trying to fix the problem, but when that failed, it was removed from the list.

Comment: @Servy Super User and Server Fault are still given prominent options for closing. The second tier ("Other") is currently Meta, Superuser (again?), TeX, DBA and Stats. If it was removed, it wasn't removed very well.

Comment: @tadman I said server fault, not super user.  The super user migration path hasn't had problems the way SF has.

Comment: @Servy I'm saying *both* Server Fault and Super User are still top-tier "Off-Topic" selections. If it's problematic then why is it there?

Comment: @tadman That's not a migration path to SF, it's merely a statement that questions asking about server management aren't on topic on SO.

Comment: @Servy This is *precisely* what I'm asking for here. I think a lot of people are reading too much into my request. I've adjusted the phrasing if that helps.

Comment: @tadman So what does that accomplish that the existing close reasons don't?

Comment: @Servy Why do we even have canned reasons, then? Why not just free-form everything? A lot of people don't even know that these other sites exist, and when I mention them they're like "Huh".

Comment: @tadman Why does the fact that the existing canned reasons already cover these questions mean that we shouldn't have canned reasons?  We have canned reasons because there are certain common problems with questions; the canned reasons cover the most common of those reasons.  There already is a good reason that covers these questions, unclear, and so there's no reason for another.  Additionally, in the fictional world where there was no good canned reason, that doesn't mean you add a canned reason for every possible problem; you add canned reasons for the *most common* problems.

Comment: @Servy Mis-matched language is a *common* problem. I'm asking for this because it's becoming more frequent, and as such, more annoying to properly close these.

Comment: I usually use "unclear what you're asking" and I think that's what I've seen most other people use as well. Maybe the text in that close reason could be expanded slightly to include some kind of "also, questions must be in English" text that links to a help center page explaining it with links to the other language sites? Although that page doesn't currently exist as far as I know.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Exactly the problem. An option that clarifies the language requirements plus links, clearly, to other options would solve a lot of these problems. The "Close" dialog pre-dates the existence of these other communities.

Answer (score 19):

Nope.

Given that the vast majority of us can't speak all of those languages, we have no way of determining if we're *not* migrating a crap question to that site.  Closing it and leaving a link to the site *might* be preferable, but I don't believe that anything further is warranted.

Comment: Crap question or not, it's clearly in the wrong place, and pointing people in the right direction is the best call. Not having this option in the first place just makes it *annoying* to do, not impossible.

Comment: "pointing people in the right direction" can be done with a comment. Migrating a bad question forces other people to do even more work to deal with it again.

Comment: @tadman:  We still have high standards of questions that get migrated across the network.  At no point should we migrate a question that we're not ***certain*** is going to be high quality and get the attention it needs.  Given that we don't understand most of the languages in that list, at least one of those conditions fails.

Comment: @Makoto Many of the "Close" options don't migrate, so I don't see a problem with it simply posting an advisory automatically. Having an option saying "This question is in Spanish and should be on the Spanish site" as a recommendation is fine, but at least *something* in there that represents that case versus a tedious, frequent, and 100% manual comment.

Comment: @tadman Telling people to go and post a question, when it's not necessarily appropriate for them to go somewhere and post a question, is not productive.  It's just like migrating the question, except it's a bit more work on the question author to go and copy-paste their question.  They need to learn how to figure out what questions a given site allows, and how to ask an appropriate question on that site, not just be given a different URL to dump their question on.  Just trying to dump your trash on other sites isn't helpful, for *anyone*.

Comment: @Servy In that case there should be a "Stack Overflow is an English only site" option, but there's absolutely nothing in the default options to deal with this sort of language mismatch.

Comment: @tadman So basically your new close reason would be `(language) => unclear + language is off-topic` (forgive the pseudo lambda). So ultimately you could achieve the same effect without modifying the system at all by closing as unclear and leaving a comment explaining that we only accept questions in English here. For something that happens extremely rarely, the cost of the implementation is too high.

Comment: @tadman:  Okay, suppose they posted their question in Chinese.  That's not a language we support at *all*.  Why should the close reason be different than if they spoke a language that we *did* have in the network?  Providing a *link* is sufficient in my mind, since we're not promised that they can even understand English to comprehend that their question is in the wrong place.

Comment: @tadman There's already a perfectly acceptable option.   "Unclear" is entirely appropriate as a reason for a question asked in another language, as it's *not* clear to the users here.  But, as you've already been told, if you really want to say that, you can use a custom close reason, so feel free to do that if you prefer.

Comment: @TinyGiant How is adding another option with boilerplate text "too high" a development cost? I can understand the migration issues and so on, but a standard "Not English" disclaimer cannot be that development intensive.

Comment: @Makoto Obviously only the sites which exist should be recommended, we can't possibly handle every case, but it seems like a disservice to the other communities to not even mention them. Even if the question is junk it's better for that community to assess than the English site to black-hole it.

Comment: @tadman No, it's not.  That's precisely the point.  Having SO send all of it's junk to other sites has a long track record of being harmful for those sites, and the people having their questions sent there.

Comment: @tadman the reason is that any reason to move a question will used incorrectly and be a burden for the target site.  IF I don't speak the language, how am I supposed to be able to tell the differences between different languages that use the Latin alphabet.  Maybe I know a little Spanish, but given the similarities, maybe the question is actually in Italian or Portuguese.  Even worse, what if someone posts it in a Cyrillic alphabet language.  I couldn't tell you if it was actually Russian, or if it Ukrainian or another language that uses the cyrillic script.  You are trusting users to know.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Although ideally the site itself would recognize what language it is and flag it automatically, Chrome does this automatically, but that's a lot to ask for. Right now if I manually flag it it sometimes goes to vote and sometimes insta-closes with my comment. I don't see how that's any better than having it as a first-class "This is not English" closing option. I think people are able to identify that it is *not English* and therefore should be closed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Flagging it as "This question is not English and is off-topic. (link to other Stack Overflow sites)" or something would be completely adequate and addresses your concerns there. I'm not asking for anything more.

Comment: Why not use "off-topic" -> "other", @tadman? Pretty sure there is a user script floating around that lets you keep a library of standard comments for that close reason.

Comment: @JoshCaswell How is that better than adding a simple option to the close menu which people can pick when the question is obviously not English?

Comment: If you're just proposing "This ain't English" as a close reason then I could see a case for that, @tadman. Your question and earlier comments seem to suggest that there should be one such reason for _each_ other language. I don't know that anyone else perceives a need for all those.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Hopefully discussions like this help find solutions. Having a singular "This is not English" option with a list of other sites people *might* try is better than nothing. If migrating is a problem I can see how that would be best avoided. There just has to be a better option than "type stuff in yourself every time". It'd just be nice if those options were advertised better when appropriate rather than staying buried in the secret footer section.

Comment: @tadman I said "implementation cost" not "development cost". There are more costs to implementation than just the time it costs to develop the implementation. You also have the space required for the new item(s) in the close dialog, as well as the testing costs and much more.

Comment: "This ain't English" - is this correctly spelled @Josh? I thought it should be written as [必须用英语吗](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/165773 "'is English required?'")