# Provide localized strings directing users to their language specific SO

Tags: feature-request, localization

I recently saw a question on SO that looked like it was written in Russian. I posted a comment suggesting they use ru.stackoverflow.com but realized *they might not understand my comment*.

Is there a place we could put correctly localized suggestions to use a different language SO that we could copy/paste from?

To be clear: I'm [**not** suggesting we auto-migrate the questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362008/closing-as-off-topic-update-for-wrong-language). Just that we have a means of telling the questioner there's a resource in their language.

Comment: The philosophy of "don't migrate crap" still applies here.  How can you objectively tell that a question written in Russian would still be a good question to ask on the Russian SO?

Comment: @Makoto Obviously I can't; but the standing policy (or at least how most users react) seems to be to direct such question askers to the appropriate language site.

Comment: I don't recall there being a formal policy on *directing* users to other foreign language sites.  I recall the policy being closing these questions as "unclear", though.

Comment: Possibly related? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362008/closing-as-off-topic-update-for-wrong-language

Comment: @Don'tPanic:  Holy crap, I'm glad I stayed consistent after five months.  Good find. :D

Comment: Note that I'm not saying we should do anything but close the questions and leave a comment; I'm just suggesting we localize the comment

Comment: Everybody understands a URL.  But that is unwelcoming, all you have to do is vote "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: It still baffles me how you can possibly work as a programmer anywhere in the world without knowing English. Sounds like an awesome way to ensure one remains 10 years behind everyone else...

Comment: Shouldn't this be the job of Stack Overflow proper? Like, show a country specific banner to first visitors with appropriate `accept-language` settings, like Amazon does

Comment: @Lundin then I recommend you read [this article](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2818719) (which is behind a pay wall, but maybe circumventable).

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Yes, it should, as several other things should be. But our priorities are not SE's priorities, sadly. Our pain points are less important than SE's bottom line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been using these. The Spanish and Portuguese ones are from Google Translate (but I was able to fix a couple of minor things in the Spanish one). I have enough of a romance language education to know they're not *complete* rubbish. The Russian one was corrected by [Quassnoi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) (a native Russian speaker). The Japanese one was provided by [Tetsuya Yamamoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6378815/tetsuya-yamamoto).

#### Spanish:

> Las preguntas y respuestas aquí deben estar escritas en inglés. Por favor utiliza http://es.stackoverflow.com. (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use https://es.stackoverflow.com/.)

#### Portuguese:

> Perguntas e respostas aqui devem ser escritas em inglês. Use http://pt.stackoverflow.com, por favor. (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use http://pt.stackoverflow.com.)

#### Russian:

*(Edited by [Quassnoi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi), a native Russian speaker)*

> Вопросы и ответы здесь должны быть написаны на английском языке. Пожалуйста, используйте http://ru.stackoverflow.com. (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use http://ru.stackoverflow.com.)

#### Japanese:

*(Provided by [Tetsuya Yamamoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6378815/tetsuya-yamamoto), a native Japanese speaker)*

> このサイトは、すべての質問と回答で英語に書くが必要です。 [日本語版スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)を使ってください。 (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use http://jp.stackoverflow.com.)

---

One problem with the proposal might be that people who don't speak these languages can mis-identify them. I've seen several people think Portuguese was Spanish, for instance, and to someone who doesn't read Cyrillic, all Cyrillic-written languages look largely the same.

But perfection is the enemy of good. We can but try.

---

Finally: There's a Google Translation API. SO could send the non-code parts of a question to that API for language identification and, if a positive result came back for a language other than English, show a message (in English and the identified language) to the user automatically, either telling them about a relevant site (again, *without* copying their question over there automatically) or (if there isn't one; for instance, French) just telling them English is required on SO.

Comment: Proposed text for Japanese version (CMIIW): "このサイトは、すべての質問と回答で英語に書くが必要です。 [日本語版スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)を使ってください。"

Comment: Currently I'm living overseas but Japanese is my mother language. I apologize if proposed text is not perfect, but still implying "all questions and answers should be written in English on this site".

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - Great! I just wanted to be able to say you were a native Japanese speaker. :-)

Answer (score 12):

I had this exact same idea two years ago, [when I posted this CW answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323329/6083675) to a question where I asked if it was OK to direct people to the non-English SOs (the answer I came to was yes, it's OK). The intention was that people would edit that answer to add translations (if you speak Russian, Spanish, Japanese, or Portuguese please consider adding a translation there!). Unfortunately, nobody really did (except for me really), so most of the comments are in very simple English, except for the name of the language (these comments may need revision, since I think it might redundantly mention the language of the site):

> You should try [ru.SO]. It's in Russian (на русском).

> You should try [jp.SO]. It's in Japanese (日本語版).

> You should try [es.SO]. It's in Spanish (en español).

> You should try [pt.SO]. It's in Portuguese (em Português).

Plus, there's this comment for Portuguese, which I took from [Renan's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323188/6083675).

> Você parece estar falando em Português. Este é o Stack Overflow em Inglês e aqui é necessário que todos os posts estejam nesse idioma. Dê uma olhada no [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), onde você pode conversar com outros programadores em Português.