# What should I do with questions that clearly belong on another SE site, but aren't in the migration options?

Tags: discussion, migration

Trying to ask the question in a way that doesn't run into cross-site politics.

When a question belongs on another site, what exactly am I intended to do with it? Leaving a comment manually has always seemed awkward, like it requires a personal rebuke from me rather than simply using the software to keep things organized. Is that really my only option, or the intended one?

---

P.S. I get that the codereview.SE people don't seem to think SO people are good at identifying migration targets; but when I tried to look up [why the migration options are as they are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318521/how-are-the-sites-that-appear-in-the-belongs-on-another-site-in-the-stack-excha) (and OP's reasoning, 3 years ago, is the same as mine), the provided answer explicitly shows stats that codereview.SE at the time was a fairly successful migration target - better, in fact, than stats.SE.

Comment: Close it as off-topic if it's off-topic. If none of the canned reasons fit use a custom one.

Comment: If it *clearly* belongs to another stack, then write a custom reason "I vote to close because it belongs to something.se". But make sure it *clearly* belongs to another stack first - if the question seems like it's, say, for physics it doesn't automatically mean it should be moved to physics. Namely, it has to fit the quality requirements of the other site, as well. Don't just try to hand off the hot potato for somebody else to deal with.

Comment: Also, specifically for CodeReview - I see a lot of people suggesting a question is moved there but rarely are the questions on topic. Somebody dumping code and saying (some variation of) "Is this good?" doesn't make it a good question for CodeReview. Especially if they've just dumped a something like a single function/method or a single loop. Check [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Finally, the statistics there do show that CR had a good history of question migration but remember that this is *without* random people having a baked in migration target. I imagine the stats would look *way* worse if that was available, as it's very easy for 5 people who have no clue about CR's policies to vote to move to CR.

Comment: The stats are skewed because moderators act as gatekeepers. We get a plenty of flags asking for migration that we decline and that’s not reflected in the migration stats.

Comment: Also make sure the question *doesn't* fit here. Lots of questions are reasonably on-topic for multiple sites, and it's up to the asker to decide where they want it to go in that case.

Comment: This is absolutely one of the most annoying things.I usually just leave a comment suggesting they repost on the other site but it's ridiculous that it can't be automated. If some sites have a lot of rejected migrations keep them off the list of options, don't eliminate all of the others.  I am positive that there will not be a lot of rejected  Wordpress, Joomla or Drupal migrations just to name a few.

Comment: There will be, @Elin, because people tend to see an off-topic question and immediately think to migrate it to another site. They fail to first ask themselves, is this a *good* question, something that is worth migrating? If it isn't, then it'll get closed on the other site, too, and that just makes more work for everyone. This sounds pretty cynical, but in my experience, if the asker can't figure out that their question is off-topic for the site where they're asking it, they probably didn't manage to ask a high-quality question either.

Comment: @CodyGray  Actually many people don't realize that there are specific sites for some topics. I follow two tags that have specific sites and really the ideal thing would be for if a user applies one of those tags they should be notified that those sites exist.  Those questions are on topic for SO most of the time but the are more likely to get good answers on  the other sites. I am perfectly able to tell that something is a bad question and should not be migrated.

Comment: @Elin Questions should *only* be migrated to other sites if they are off-topic where they’re asked. Moderators regularly rejected migration requests for questions that are on-topic for Stack Overflow. The fact that you think one could get a better answer elsewhere isn’t the migration criteria that we follow.

Comment: People use SE sites to get their questions answered. If they knew that internal SE incentives were **not** aligned with getting them to the place where the question will get the best answer, isn't that a reason not to use SE?