# Why does SO not add more sites to "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"? - Close reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, migration

This has been an issue for about 9 years (earliest post I could found was from June 2011, see below) now and I personally feel very uncomfortable with that it isn't fixed already. I clearly say "fixed" because I personally consider it as bug.

When we close question for the reason that it belongs to another site we have by far too less options.

Let's take have a look at it:

[image]

We only got 5 options here. To vote to a migrate a question to Meta, Superuser, Tex/Latex, DBA and statistics site.

Why?

We urgently need more options here.

The ones I personally really **need** to be in here are:

- https://askubuntu.com/ (For the ones dedicated to the Ubuntu system and not programming)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/   (For questions regarding Linux or Unix but not related to programming)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (For the ones like "My code works fine but how can I make it more efficient?")
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ (For seeking advice in software engineering in general without focus to programming)
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (For the whole amount of questions seeking for specific software apps)
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/ (For the ones focusing generic computer science)

And the directly related ones:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Related:

- [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/12139179)

---

I'm aware of that this has been asked before and that there are several posts already on SO Meta regarding the same concern,

- [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251652/12139179)
- [Add "Flag as Other" checkbox to "Vote to Close as Off-Topic" dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160929/674989)
- [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96205/674989)
- [Better "Flag for migration" interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210545/674989)
- [What should I do with questions that clearly belong on another SE site, but aren't in the migration options?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390549/)
- [Can we have more options in the Closing > Off-Topic > Migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253869/)

but anyhow it seems that nothing get changed nor that Stack Overflow states anything about why not doing it from their side although it is so much needed and just declined some of these feature-requests without statements again.

In opposite, it seems that SO even made things more complicated as it removed the ability to suggest migrations - the "should be migrated to ... by a moderator" feature:

[image]

I could found no official statement for the reasons of the removal of this feature with or without asking the community whether this is a good decision or not.

---

I feel it very, very, very very annoying to me as user to go and find the a link to the respective site and post it into the comments of such questions to suggest OP or mods the migration to other sites.

- Why can't we just flag a post to be migrated to another side when the case is appropriate? Why do you bothering us to flag the post for a mod and explain why it fits better there?

---

#### Argumentations against:

1. I've found some argumentation that such questions should be flagged for a moderator instead with a comment added to inform the mod to which site the post should be migrated to.

   But what is this for an unbelievable detour?

   This also requires again research from the user to which site to migrate to. I need to find the links  to the other sites and look if it is appropriate.

   For the most users, they won't take this obstacle and just leave the post as it is and continue to the next one.
2. Another argumentation is that migrations would not be used frequently or would not be used if they were there.

- But **How can you measure a traffic for something what isn't even there?**

  One cannot say that the features wouldn't be used before at least making a test.

---

Wouldn't it be much easier to just provide the sites in the list for everyone? I don't see where the problem is.

Why SO, Why do you give us such hurdles to actually keep the network a clean place and separate non-low quality posts where they belong to?

Comment: Code review don't want to be a migration target, seems rather rude to ignore their wishes. Do you know the other migration targets you're proposing are in favour of this? If not, surely that's the first step here before even asking this question.

Comment: @RobertLongson A question belongs to there, if it belongs to there. Mods clearly have the competence to decide whether it does or not. The problem is about not being able to give at least the opportunity to give a respective flag which is a difference.

Comment: did you ask at metas of the listed sites whether they want to be in migration targets?

Comment: Let's get rid of it entirely. The vast majority of *custom moderator flags* that I see suggesting migrating are horribly misguided, and these are people who took extra time to type in a message.  People suggest migrating questions that are (a) perfectly on-topic for the site where they're asked, (b) not even close to on-topic for another site, and/or (c) so terribly low quality that nobody wants that garbage. I'm not sure users should be trusted to vote to migrate anything, unless they also have close-vote powers on the other site. They certainly don't need *more* choices.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I'm coming to a party at your house. What time should I turn up? I've invited all my friends too.

Comment: @gnat If they don't be able to decide whether questions belong to there communities or not, then I'm asking myself "Why do we have separated communities then at all?"

Comment: @CodyGray That is a lack on the user-side. Maybe higher the threshold of rep then for users who be able to cast such votes. That many users do it bad, doesn't mean to completely erase the feature.

Comment: @RobertLongson My house isn't a disco. So go with your friends to make a party *where it belongs to*.

Comment: If the question is off-topic here, vote to close it. If it's on-topic somewhere else you can add a comment with your opinion and the poster can repost it if they wish.

Comment: @RobertLongson I do that frequently and feel annoying with. Why not enhancing this process?

Comment: The point is if code review is a migration target the people that are actually active on code review are afraid that we'll swamp it with bad content. I'm afraid as a community we've shown we can't be trusted not to do that. We're the 600lb gorilla here.

Comment: @RobertLongson Understand that. But they could make a layer of "approval" then by mods or even community members to decide whether a question should be migrated or not.

Comment: @Amessihel The thing is to improve and eliminate that the user *needs* to do so. I do that frequently and feel very annoying with. It is also very ponderous for the user her/himself to repost the question. It also leaves the "wasted one" for a moderator of the origin community to clean up and going into in the overfilled queue.

Comment: Only tbe OP should migrate questions by copying to the target AND deleting from the source.  The OP is the user who has the best chance of accurately targeting or retargeting, their question.  The grunt work of identifying a better-match site, where the question is on-topic and will not fall foul siite policy/rules should be done by the OP - the only user who has the full context of the question.  If the OP mis-targeted their question in the first place, the OP should fix it.

Comment: It's also the OP that will receive a potential barrage of downvotes and complaints if a question is wrongly migrated.

Comment: @MartinJames In such case, we close the question as "off-topic" very soon. If the OP got no information from a helpful user where the question really belongs to, her/his concern will probably never be answered. Maybe s/he goes to other communities like Quora then to ask the same concern.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio 'layer of "approval" then by mods or even community members to decide whether a question should be migrated or not', OK, fine, please publish your email address where you wish to receive links to migration requests.

Comment: @MartinJames We already have excellent moderation tools for community members, f.e. close, reopen and edit queue's. Why not adding another queue for reviewing? If it really doesn't happen so much as an argumentation against it says, it wouldn't make so much work extra.

Comment: @ivarni That's the cross we all have to hold when it comes to asking questions. Again, I suggest user with knowledge about whether it fits to a target to decide to migrate a question or not. Not any user who think it might fit.

Comment: If we make it clear that automated migration is only for perfectly good question based on destination rules. And not current site nor user appreciation. Especially for Code Review. where we have a metric of poor question that get advice to go to CR.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio OK, if that is done, I will just ignore that queue as, I strongly suspect, will many others.

Comment: Imo codereview.stackexchange, 
softwareengineering.stackexchange, 
softwarerecs.stackexchange, and
cs.stackexchange are not directly compatible due to their exigence in quality. We should ask to their meta if they want us to be able to things with 4 clicks and what are the rules and process.

Comment: @DragandDrop. 'Eh... another nag rule..click'.  Many users ignore anything that might interfere with their primary goal of getting an answer. Nothing else matters:(

Comment: We're 10 million visits a day with 13 million users, Code review has fewer than 2000 people with review capability. They would spend all their time clicking on "no" on the migration destination queue, or more likely ignore it altogether so all the migrations fail. Going to a queue and seeing a torrent of off-topic questions is going to be dispiriting. Spend a few days doing Help and Improvement reviews here and see if you don't agree.

Comment: you kind of underestimate size difference in sites. Those you proposed to add to migration victims are 100x-1000x smaller than Stack Overflow and if hundreds of uneducated SO users start migratinig inappropriate stuff these sites simply get flooded with closed or close-worthy questions. This already happened in the past and they had to escalate to the company to block the garbage flow: [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134636/165773)

Comment: @DragandDrop No community should be forced of course, but every party *can* profit from a trade-off in that topic IMHO.

Comment: Migration, especiallly any kind of automated migration, is deader than Tesla short sellers.

Comment: @Amessihel Another solution could be to make the communication with the OP easier. Like an "I suggest you to place this question on X" feature, but most people unfortunately will consider something like that as useless.

Comment: @RobertLongson Wouldn't that mean to leave "code review" questions on SO while they usually would belong to Code Review by the rules? Isn't the whole concept of separating questions then broken? Leaving Code Review the silent beautiful place it ever was without considering the reason why it was build up?

Comment: That's the cross we all have to hold when it comes to asking questions on the wrong site. Closing the question should be enough to clue the OP in on the fact that they're in the wrong place.

Comment: @ivarni The purpose of SE is to give and find help. When doing so, it would give more problems to someone who is seeking help and high-probably s/he won't get the advice s/he wants to. Stack Overflow is the flagship and new users tend to shoot questions on the flag ship without seeking further information that it might not fit. That is horrible, but I see no sufficient handling from the side of SE to prevent that in the first place before even asking a question. If we don't have a sufficient reaction in such cases, we cannot show him s/he was wrong and what exactly was wrong, which is bad.

Comment: Migration suggestions require the suggester to be familiar with the target site rules/policy and to be sure that the question does not violate them.  That is ditch-digging work that the OP should do.  If the migration backfires, the OP should be the one with a face full of buckshot.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio ..and getting involved with migrating questions from other users is worse.

Comment: There are not enough mods to do the work that already exists, never mind adding migration hassle.  We need more effective mods. The 'regular' SO curators are also overloaded.  We need more effective curators.  We don't need more ditch-digging.

Comment: @MartinJames "*Migration suggestions require the suggester to be familiar with the target site rules/policy and to be sure that the question does not violate them.*" - If one got the required privileges to cast a vote and one is confirm with that, why should s/he not be able to make such suggestions? - "*That is ditch-digging work that the OP should do. If the migration backfires, the OP should be the one with a face full of buckshot.*" - Well, yes but why give the OP such obstacles instead of to guide to the right place? It's not very helpful and rude...

Comment: ...SE is one company, why not make more connections? "*..and getting involved with migrating questions from other users is worse.*" - Why is that worse? It helps cleaning up. --- "*There are not enough mods to do the work that already exists, never mind adding migration hassle. We need more effective mods.*" - That the community has not enough mods can't be made as argument here and I feel personally very bored by this argumentation. There are much users which want to help, but don't get into the position to do so. If you need more moderators to help, instate more. Easy as that.

Comment: So basically your point is 'I do too much work to do this. SE should have more ppl do that work for me'. Stack doesn't have enough ppl moderating the queues HERE. So ... That can't work. And the size difference makes the migration targets you talk of unsuitable... While I get the intent..... I don't think it's practical

Comment: If I check your profile against the list of migration targets I wonder how you are so sure that you need those targets? I expect you would need substantial participation on each site to make the perfect judgement call. Did you check on the Meta of those sites you propose if they are open to accept the posts you plan to send there?

Comment: @Patrice As I already said, too less mods and difference in size between the networks doesn't mean in turn that things are good this way and couldn't be changed. I doubt that the size difference is important. It is important how many posts would be migrated from the destination and how much work this in fact would be. I not read fully through the made answer as well as their given links. Maybe I late come back with more insights.

Comment: @rene My profile is completely irrelevant to the feature-request. It is like trying to improve the engine of a car and focusing the driver. Others made the request too as you can see inside of the linked posts. So did I.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio 'If you need more moderators to help, instate more. Easy as that', great, so, you are going to stand for moderator, then?

Comment: @MartinJames TravisJ and Dharman truely wanted the place and had been a good help as well as Tschallaka I think.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting downvoted. This is a legitimate concern?

Comment: @user16217248 It's a feature request; on meta feature requests, a downvote means "this feature request should not be implemented."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the sites in your list already has been a migration target. This has proven to work poorly (softly speaking) and after much trouble they had to escalate to the company to get removed from that list, see [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134636/165773)

To prevent impression that this is some exceptional case, other migration target sites in the past had similar difficulties followed with escalation requesting their removal from the list, for example see here: [Regarding the high number of rejected migrations from Stack Overflow to Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150206/165773)

You see, changes like you propose carry some risk of causing frustration and much moderation load at target sites, along with waste of company development effort on adding then deleting target sites in migration list.

Because of above, I think it would be unwise to fulfill your request (and all similar requests for that matter) without some preliminary safety check to ensure that mentioned risk is not too high.

---

Natural and possibly simplest way to perform such preliminary check would be asking at target site meta how do they feel about getting added to migration targets. Their 10K users can also check and evaluate mod migration stats (which is sort of "optimistic estimate" for migration) to tell how risky / safe it would be to try opening it for regular SO users.

Besides, [as was pointed in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399730/so-please-add-finally-more-sites-to-this-question-belongs-on-another-site-in-th#comment784586_399730), this would be a matter of courtesy:

> I'm coming to a party at your house. What time should I turn up? I've invited all my friends too.

Comment: we could increase the numver of votes instead of three 5 for that purpose. i also wished rarely that i could send questions to serverfault or linux, because is usually don't get answers

Comment: @Amessihel comments like you suggest have proven to do more harm than good and some of the sites targeted in comments even had to establish special bots to track and report such comments to minimize harm done by misleading askers to inappropriate sites (I know that Software Engineering and Code Review do this, and maybe there are other sites)

Comment: @gnat, If true, only "closed as off-topic" should remain them.

Comment: @nbk votes for migrate at SO are [already changed to 4 in July 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97700/165773). Given that both escalations referred in my answer were much later it didn't help. And I see no reason to believe that increase from 4 to 5 would help either. As I wrote the most reliable way seems to be simply ask at target site meta

Comment: the 3 votes rule works just fine, and i can only say this for SO mysql --> dba and seeing there this works just fine, bronze and up badge helps also to eliminate rifraf. everything can be misused with that many members,

Comment: @nbk Just because it works for migrations between two small sites does not mean it will work for migrations between one gigantly yuge site and a small site. Those situations are not comparable.

Comment: @nbk yes, DBA seems to be one of the sites where migration works good enough. Unfortunately this doesn't guarantee that other will be lucky too. As I wrote, target site meta is the simplest way to evaluate chances. In particular, their 10K users can check and evaluate mod migration stats (which is sort of "optimistic estimate" for migration) to tell how risky / safe would be to try opening migration for regular users

Comment: IMO, migration feature should be completely removed (at least from SO) The only migration path that makes sense is migration to meta. Usually any question that spectacularly misses the site is also very poor question. I would add generic off topic close reason about question belonging to some other site with link to all SE sites and instruction to read help center before asking on any particular site.

Comment: Removing migration feature would hopefully remove the increasing number of users that request better sites in the question itself or in comments. Like it is our job to do point them in right direction.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think I saw at MSE stories about how migration works well between some smaller sites. Possible reason to keep migration is company may simply consider it cheaper to have occasional misguided meta requests like this one than deal with possible complaints from sites that had it worked well in case of removal

Comment: @gnat i looked at the statistics for migration and they seem, completely normal to me, there is a small flow between sites and almost none are rejected.

Comment: @nbk digits alone don't make it, sorry - note my answer says "evaluate". How much increase to expect after opening regular migration path? What changes to expect in success rate after that? Would possible increase in rejections be acceptable for target site? Etc. I would prefer that target site regulars answer these questions and not some random 10K user at source site who may have no slightest idea about topics and norms of target site

Comment: ^^^ as an example, I just happen to be active at one of the sites listed in this question. And because of that I am aware about some additional data allowing me provide fairly reliably estimates for above questions. But, if I was active only on Stack Overflow, I would have no idea about it. This data is public and anyone can get it but the thing is, it is of no interest for SO user

Comment: @gnat even i as random 100k user have a good idea when a question is better suited for another site, and i usually comment after proking aroud to try the user luck elsewhere usuially serverfault or DBA in rare cases, every site ahs their share of offtopic question what differnce make the 100 more.

Comment: @nbk past experience with comments suggesting migration to various sites speaks rather against your assumption, I already mentioned this in [one of my previous comments here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399730/so-please-add-finally-more-sites-to-this-question-belongs-on-another-site-in-th/399732?noredirect=1#comment784631_399732). I can believe that your comments are typically correct but unfortunately this seems to be exception rather than a rule

Comment: Nonetheless, I think it is good to just talk about that it instead of to just keep firing at me with mostly opinion-based argumentation. Talk about it to deescalate conflicts. I'm thankful for providing the real examples and that it might not be the best way to go altough it could have been useful. So if I want to post to be migrated I flag it for mod intervention and give the specific reason right? Or should I directly carry it to Meta? Or discuss it at the Meta of the target?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio do I understand it correctly that you are now looking for advice about mod migration (as opposed to adding a target site to close dialog)? If yes, then most smooth examples I've seen were like this 1) wait until it's closed at source site (as a proof that they don't want it) 2) drop to target site chat asking if they want it migrated 3) if they say yes, flag for moderator with the reference to chat discussion. Step #3 is sometimes "hijacked" by target site regulars when they choose to just flag it themselves instead of waiting for you to do that

Comment: ...if you have enough reputation at the target site, you can also try a bit riskier way, ie skip step #2 and flag immediately pointing to your experience at target site in flag message. I think I even did this myself once or twice, although I generally prefer chat, to make sure that other site regulars would agree with me