# Should Server Fault be added to the "belongs on another site" dialog when citing a close vote reason?

Tags: discussion

The current dialog looks like this when selecting *Community Specific Reason* → *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange Network*:

[image: What site does this question belong on?]

Stack Overflow is a programming site, but many novices and professionals here (myself included) use Stack Overflow for scripting help when it comes to system administrator and DevOps-style tasks. At times some of the system commands might be at fault and it truly isn't a problem with the script or programming. In these cases, [Super User](https://superuser.com) is a welcome place to put questions that fall squarely within "so-and-so utility is throwing X error", but [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) is better when we are talking about software and solutions that are typically not used by the hobbyist, or when you have a question about using software or a software's errors in an enterprise setting.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758488/cant-install-metasploitable3-get-error-error-building-the-vagrant-box-using-pack) where Super User may not be the appropriate place to put this question, and Server Fault would be a better place for it due to the enterprise use case of [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29). That said, if I just leave a comment there is no migration path for the question I'm aware of. Unless I'm mistaken (and I suppose I could be), questions are only candidate for migration if one of the selections on the `What site does this question belong on?` dialog box.

Should Stack Overflow consider adding Server Fault to this list? Or perhaps a better solution might be to allow the user to specify the community if it's not in the list?

Comment: Are you sure your example is a question that *should* be migrated? Is it acceptable over at Server Fault? Because it seems like it's lacking some details but I'm also not using Server Fault, so my assessment might be off. We do have [this close reason](https://i.imgur.com/EUWBdiY.png) that seems more applicable.

Comment: ....this is what I get for Stack Overflowing pre-coffee :D but then why doesn't the ServerFault option show in the same place as the other sites? I would argue these should be displayed in the same location.

Comment: Because it's not a migration path. It's a different close reason.

Comment: Why not offer a migration path if the question is better suited for another site in SE? Why are we limited only to five communities?

Comment: 1. Because the close vote decisions are capped to 5 per page. 2. I'm on the opinion that we shouldn't have migration votes. Except for meta. Getting a *good* question that can be migrated wholesale is rare enough that I think we can just rely on a modflag for those. We don't want to migrate questions that will be closed.

Comment: @Bender Here's the answer to that last question at least: [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654) Any question can be migrated to any Stack by moderators, but those particular flag options are supposed to exist because those specific migration paths are the most common *and most successful* (Few post-migration closures). Now, whether those options have been reevaluated recently, and are still current, is a different question, but that's the long-standing reasoning for why Site X but not Site Y.

Comment: Yes it should be there and also a bunch more of them sadly the space is limited

Comment: My approach is to close, recommend the asker ask the question at the better-fitting SE site, and drop a link to that site's How to Ask help pages with a strong recommendation that they read the help and tweak the question to make sure it's inline with the other site's rules and expectations.

Comment: [did you ask about this at Server Fault meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399732/839601) "I'm coming to a party at your house. What time should I turn up? I've invited all my friends too."

Comment: But @gnat shouldn't we all share in the joys of the glorious Eternal September?

Comment: @user4581301 what I find particularly funny is, SF indeed _were_ a migrated target once upon a time, and they [requested removal from that list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150206/165773)

Answer (score 7):

Let me ask you this: would you be willing to upvote the question you link to if it was posted on Server Fault instead? If not, it should be closed, not migrated. We should only vote to migrate high-quality questions that we're sure are on-topic on the target site.

That being said, many people don't follow that standard when voting to migrate, so target sites end up receiving low-quality questions. Also, given that people who post off-topic questions here typically haven't read any of the help center documentation, many questions are low-quality and don't meet either site's quality standards. That being said, I rarely see questions that I'm sure should be migrated.

Also, in practice, with the threshold for close votes being lowered, voting to migrate effectively requires unanimous agreement among the close voters, which is quite difficult to achieve.

Comment: Makes you wonder if this closure path should just be removed entirely so it no longer acts as a misleading signpost.