# Move all off-topic questions to their own sites?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

This is a suggestion, to move all off-topic questions to their own site. For instance, why are there still a lot of [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) and [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) questions on Stack Overflow?

There was [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) from the beginning, and there is [a vi/Vim site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tour), but still, we see a lot of vi questions. This is also true for other similar off-topics.

An example Vim question: *[How do I move to end of line in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105721/how-do-i-move-to-end-of-line-in-vim)*

Comment: If they are on-topic on SO, there is no reason to migrate them.

Comment: @JeanneDark thank you for stating that vim questions are on-topic but I just give an example. are you are saying that there are no old off-topic questions staying on SO?

Comment: downvoters can you explain why? we are in 2021 and the overall UX of off-topicness of questions on SO is still not as good as it could be. And as you see from the answer it is not a thing too obvious for everybody.

Comment: Being off-topic here doesn't make a question on-topic somewhere else. Do you know what is in scope for Seasoned Advice?

Comment: some downvotes here may be because some may expect that [one would first ask at target site meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399732/839601) whether they want migrations from Stack Overflow. "I'm coming to a party at your house. What time should I turn up? I've invited all my friends too."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things:

1. Questions about tools that developers use **are** on topic for Stack Overflow, for issues that are "unique to software development". Even with that caveat there is always going to be some overlap.
2. Off topic questions shouldn't be offloaded to other sites willy nilly. We have to make sure that a) we're certain they're on topic for the other site. and b) they're a high quality question.

Your example probably doesn't satisfy point 1, but unless it's a really stellar question it's probably not going to satisfy 2. b).

In fact most off-topic questions don't satisfy 2. b) so they don't get migrated.

Comment: "Questions about tools that developers use are on topic for Stack Overflow" as long as they are "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: @Braiam True, but unfortunately that's a grey area. I know in this case it's probably fairly clear cut, but in others - not so much.

Comment: If the question's older than 60 days it also cannot be migrated anymore.

Comment: Nice to know about that,  and it's an important thing to know, and the question form is not much helpful on this. which leads to the suggestion of this feature to automatically recognize this and give better suggestions on asking the question on the original site or not. also in the search of both sites if there are overlaps it's good to load related questions from other sites.