# Feature request: grouping for 'other sites on the network'

Tags: feature-request

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69766249/importerror-no-module-named-commandnotfound-db-creator) is a perfectly decent question which belongs on Ask Ubuntu.  It could go to Super User, but it will get better answers from somebody who knows the internals of [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29).

I realise that [the 'other' sites are chosen based on frequency of migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318521/how-are-the-sites-that-appear-in-the-belongs-on-another-site-in-the-stack-excha) and the done thing [is to select 'other' when voting to close and ask a moderator to move the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options/251654#251654).  However, I can't think of a question which would be on-topic on Ask Ubuntu which would *not* be potentially on-topic on Super User, and I can't think of a question on Super User mentioning ubuntu which wouldn't be on-topic for Ask Ubuntu.  (Of course, there are plenty of questions from users merely running Ubuntu which wouldn't.)

In the past, an open 'other' move option has been rejected for what are probably good reasons.  But would it be possible to have some kind of *grouping* for off-topic sites?  This would require SO to know that e.g. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), Super User, and Ask Ubuntu are all the same *kind* of site, and that could be difficult with the more esoteric sites, but for the questions which come up on SO I don't think it would be so hard.

As per the comment, this would effectively be a tree structure: the first node would be the category and the second nodes per branch would be the individual sites.  The decision of which sites to include would be done exactly the same way, only with the category, so it would still be impossible to migrate to some completely unreleated site.  Note that I *don’t* suggest doing this for every site, only for the targets for migration from SO, which are necessarily pretty limited.*

If this has been asked before and rejected, I'd be interested to know why: it strikes me as a workable halfway house between an open move option and the current situation.

*I'm assuming completely off-topic questions, e.g. using the `first-aid` tag to ask about first aid (sic!) will just be closed with a comment.

**Edit** The first version of this question incorrectly read the linked question on frequency of migration as implying that this choice was *automatic*.  But it being manual seems to make this even easier.

Comment: Then what? If I choose 'unix' what happens, how is the system supposed to figure out which site you mean? Or are you asking for some kind of tree structure. At any rate asking for more options is asked a lot and denied a lot. The fact remains that as a group we're collectively terrible at migrating questions, i.e. we try to migrate terrible questions all the time.

Comment: @RobertLongson I buy that last point: after all, some are sites are pretty specific.  For the former yes, I'm asking for a tree structure, albeit one only 2 nodes deep.  The algorithm would then select the top nodes as it currently selects the targets, so there would still be filtering.  (I.e. there would be no risk of some completely irrelevant site coming up)

Comment: Who said they're "chosen automatically"? That's not what the linked question says.

Comment: @CodeGray bother, I misread that.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: Migration is generally problematic, because we would have to know what is on topic on other sites, and many of users don't know that, including moderators. IMO migration should not be an option for most questions as most of questions that have completely missed the site are of rather poor quality. I would just leave off topic closure that would list all other technical sites and with instructions to read their help center before posting question on any of them.

Comment: *"which belongs on AskUbuntu"* -  Why? It's about installing a tool primarily used by programmers, that's explicitly on topic

Comment: @Nick if I read it correctly it's about breaking ubuntu's system python install breaking some script ubuntu runs in apt updates, which I think is an internal os matter.  In any case I don't have ubuntu to test and haven't used it for years.

Comment: Why bother with possible migration targets? In praxis there aren't enough people doing reviews and many votes to migrate will simply age away - a complete waste of time.

Answer (score -3):

The reasons are:

- there aren't enough reviewers to make the migration system worth investing any time in (and presumably what I describe would need a fair bit of implementation time)
- Migration is difficult anyway, and encouraging it more widely would likely lead to spamming other SE sites
- Migrated questions tend to be of poor quality, as better quality questions are generally asked in the right place to begin with.

Comment: Note that this sort of question has been asked before many times on meta. Just as on the [main] site, you really will want to search meta for similar questions before asking, and use this information to help make your question more unique and not just another rehash.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I really did, and thought this was a genuinely workable middle ground, but it doesn't matter (and I may have missed something).  I'll leave it up as the result is at any rate clear if not exactly flattering  so it may do some good